# Difference between CPPFLAGS and CXXFLAGS in GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What's the difference between CPPFLAGS and CXXFLAGS in GNU Make?

Comment: You can get make to print out its predefined variables and rules database using the invocation `make -p`

Answer (score 239, accepted):

`CPPFLAGS` is supposed to be for flags for the **C** **P**re**P**rocessor; `CXXFLAGS` is for flags for the C++ compiler.

The default rules in make (on my machine, at any rate) pass `CPPFLAGS` to just about everything, `CFLAGS` is only passed when compiling and linking C, and `CXXFLAGS` is only passed when compiling and linking C++.

Comment: it seems like a common practice that CFLAGS would also be passed when compile C++?

Comment: Ha. I get it! the `x` is a `+` turned on it's side because `C++FLAGS` would blow up the compiler. ... I may have arrived to the party late, but that's still better than arriving on time to the wrong party.

Comment: @BaiyanHuang I wouldn't think about it as common or not; you'll run into both conventions.  You have to know what your current setup is doing.

Comment: `CPPFLAGS` is **NOT** for **C** **P**lus **P**lus but `CXXFLAGS`  is.

Comment: True but terrible. This feels like we are stuck in the 80s.

Comment: So damn confusing. At first I thought `CXX` meant "both C++ and C."

Comment: The confusion may stem from the fact that the suffix for C++ source files is often `.cpp`, as in `mycode.cpp`. I have actually also seen source files with the `.cxx` suffix.

Answer (score 35):

By default, `CPPFLAGS` will be given to the C preprocessor, while `CXXFLAGS` will be given to the C++ compiler.

The [GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) is a good resource for questions like this (see [Implicit Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html#Implicit-Variables)).

Comment: I was staring right at the manual when I had this exact same question.  I typed CPPFLAGS into stackoverflow and got the answer much quicker than searching the manual.

Answer (score 19):

CPPFLAGS are for the C preprocessor, while CXXFLAGS are for the C++ compiler.

See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html).

Answer (score 0):

By default, they're set to something.

In practice, you need to know what every single project does.  Virtually no one uses those defaults built into make, and if you rely on, for example, CPPFLAGS meaning "flags to the C preprocessor" you'll find that the project you care about has used it to mean "flags to the C++ compiler" instead.  And does the CFLAGS flag get passed to C++ compile lines?  Sometimes.  Not always.  Etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Some projects use CPPFLAGS to mean "c++ flags", but those projects are almost definitely doing so out of ignorance of the standard, and it would be better if they used CXXFLAGS.

Comment: @Score_Under I don't disagree with you, but the world is filled with projects that couldn't care less what anyone thinks the standard is.  You _always_ have to investigate.