# C code compilation failure

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu, webkit, gtk

i have this makefile below and in it my includes are

gtk/gtk.h

and

webkit/webkit.h

but when i try to build the project using the make command i have the errors

error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory

error: webkit/webkit.h: No such file or directory

in case the gtk+-2.0.pc and webkit...pc are in the usr/lib/pkgconfig

Make File:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -Wall `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 webkit-1.0`
LDFLAGS+=`pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0 webkit-1.0`
INCLUDE=/usr/include
LIB=/usr/lib
SOURCES=wrapper.c wrapper.h browser.c
OBJ=browser

all:  $(SOURCES) $(OBJ)

$(OBJ): $(SOURCES)
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -I $(INCLUDE) -L $(LIB) $(SOURCES) -o $(OBJ)

clean:
 rm -rf $(OBJ)
```

Comment: Can you post the actual output from running make?

Comment: Do you have `pkg-config` installed? What's the output of `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 webkit-1.0` from the shell?

Answer (score 6):

Backticks aren't how you run shell commands in a Makefile.  Your CFLAGS and LDFLAGS lines should probably look like

```
CFLAGS=-g -Wall $(shell pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 webkit-1.0)
LDFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0 webkit-1.0)
```

Comment: While you are correct you need `$(shell ...)` to get the command to run in the Makefile, there is nothing wrong with using backticks.  With backticks, make will pass the command lines with the backtick to the shell and the shell will handle that before invoking the compiler.

Comment: there is no changes are got up

Comment: there is no wrong in the make file 
the error is in the system environment so who can i change it to have it run

Comment: @R Samuel Klatchko: You're correct.  I forgot about that behavior.

Comment: Also, using `$(shell ...)` instead of backticks means that pkg-config is only called twice (once for CFLAGS and once for LDFLAGS), instead of twice for every invocation of `$(CC)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting CXXFLAGS in addition to CFLAGS.

Comment: Actually, CXXFLAGS is for the C++ compiler. Maybe you mean CPPFLAGS? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495598/difference-between-cppflags-and-cxxflags-in-gnu-make

Answer (score 1):

The only include path you have specified is `/usr/include`, therefore it will look fo rthe files at:

```
/usr/include/gtk/gtk.h
/usr/include/webkit/webkit.h
```

Unless you have additional paths specifies in the either of the CPATH, or C_INCLUDE_PATH environment variables.

Add `usr/lib/pkgconfig` as a -I path.

Comment: `$(CFLAGS)` contains additional `-I` directives as returned from pkg-config which will specify where to find the gtk and webkit headers.

Comment: @jamessan: Except if that had worked and the files were present, it would have found them, so to add it manually is a useful investigation if not a permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually have gtk/gtk.h and webkit/webkit.h in /usr/include directory? Are the development packages providing them installed?

Comment: Yes, i have this files under the include dir

Comment: Having /usr/include/gtk/gtk.h and /usr/include/webkit/webkit.h and having changed \`...\` to $(shell ...) you should not have a problem, this makefile works with this change.