# CFLAGS vs CPPFLAGS

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf, cflags

I understand that CFLAGS (or CXXFLAGS for C++) are for the compiler, whereas CPPFLAGS is used by the preprocessor.

But I still don't understand the difference.

I need to specify an include path for a header file that is included with #include -- because #include is a preprocessor directive, is the preprocessor (CPPFLAGS) the only thing I care about?

Under what circumstances do I need to give the compiler an extra include path?

In general, if the preprocessor finds and includes needed header files, why does it ever need to be told about extra include directories?  What use is CFLAGS at all?

(In my case, I actually found that **BOTH** of these allow me to compile my program, which adds to the confusion... I can use CFLAGS ***OR*** CPPFLAGS to accomplish my goal (in autoconf context at least).  What gives?)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495598/difference-between-cppflags-and-cxxflags-in-gnu-make

Answer (score 179, accepted):

The implicit make rule for compiling a C program is

```
%.o:%.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

where the `$()` syntax expands the variables. As both `CPPFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` are used in the compiler call, which you use to define include paths is a matter of personal taste. For instance if `foo.c` is a file in the current directory

```
make foo.o CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include"
make foo.o CFLAGS="-I/usr/include"
```

will both call your compiler in exactly the same way, namely

```
gcc -I/usr/include -c -o foo.o foo.c
```

The difference between the two comes into play when you have multiple languages which need the same include path, for instance if you have `bar.cpp` then try

```
make bar.o CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include"
make bar.o CFLAGS="-I/usr/include"
```

then the compilations will be

```
g++ -I/usr/include -c -o bar.o bar.cpp
g++ -c -o bar.o bar.cpp
```

as the C++ implicit rule also uses the `CPPFLAGS` variable.

This difference gives you a good guide for which to use - if you want the flag to be used for all languages put it in `CPPFLAGS`, if it's for a specific language put it in `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` etc. Examples of the latter type include standard compliance or warning flags - you wouldn't want to pass `-std=c99` to your C++ compiler!

You might then end up with something like this in your makefile

```
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include
CFLAGS=-std=c99
CXXFLAGS=-Weffc++
```

Comment: Note that you cannot run stand-alone `cpp` using `CPPFLAGS` and expect any reasonable result because `-std=c99` affects which symbols are defined (especially in lieu of feature test macros). Instead, you need `$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -E`.

Comment: "The implicit make rule for compiling a C program is" "`$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<`" Not sure if it makes a difference, but on gmake, currently `CPPFLAGS` appears after `CFLAGS`: `$ make --version | head -n 1` ->
`GNU Make 4.3`; `$ make -p 2>/dev/null | grep -F 'COMPILE.c ='` ->
`COMPILE.c = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c`

Answer (score 14):

The `CPPFLAGS` macro is the one to use to specify `#include` directories.

Both `CPPFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` work in your case because the `make`(1) rule combines both preprocessing and compiling in one command (so both macros are used in the command).

You don't need to specify `.` as an include-directory if you use the form `#include "..."`.  You also don't need to specify the standard compiler include directory.  You do need to specify all other include-directories.

Comment: This makes more sense, but I still don't see what CFLAGS does, then.  If, as you seem to imply, compilation in more complex projects is done in a separate step from preprocessing, will preprocessing succeed but compilation fail if CFLAGS doesn't add the same paths that CPPFLAGS added for the preprocessor?

I guess I don't understand what the compiler does with include paths if the preprocessor already processed the #include directives?

Comment: @EB If you're compiling preprocessed files then include paths are unnecessary - the required headers have already been added to the preprocessed source (Have a look at the output when you run `gcc -E` on a file - there are no #includes). Most modern compilers combine the pre-processing and compilation steps, so you don't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 3):

You are after [implicit make rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules).

Answer (score 1):

To add to those who have mentioned the implicit rules, it's best to see what make has defined implicitly and for your env using:

```
make -p
```

For instance:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

which expands

```
COMPILE.c = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
```

This will also print `# environment` data. Here, you will find GCC's include path among other useful info.

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include
```

In make, when it comes to search, the paths are many, the light is one... or something to that effect.

1. `C_INCLUDE_PATH` is system-wide, set it in your shell's `*.rc`.
2. `$(CPPFLAGS)` is for the preprocessor include path.
3. If you need to add a general search path for make, use:

```
VPATH = my_dir_to_search
```

... or even more specific

```
vpath %.c src
vpath %.h include
```

make uses VPATH as a general search path so use cautiously. If a file exists in more than one location listed in VPATH, make will take the first occurrence in the list.

Answer (score 1):

`CPPFLAGS` seems to be an invention of GNU Make, referenced in some of its built-in recipes. Unlike `CFLAGS`, it is used in recipes for multiple languages, including, for example, Fortran.

If your program is built by some Free software distributions, you may find that some of them require packages to interpolate this variable, using `CPPFLAGS` for passing down options like `-D_WHATEVER=1` for passing down a macro definition.

That said, I've never seen a project advertise `CPPFLAGS` as something that is a good idea to use in order to customize its build behavior.

It seems uncommon for a distro to pass `CPPFLAGS` to all packages, and requires them to handle it (as a matter of documented fact about that distro). I seem to remember Gentoo does this; I'd love to be informed about any other.

It's not uncommon for custom build rules in projects to neglect to interpolate `$(CPPFLAGS)` into the `$(CC)` command line. Neglecting to interpolate `$(CPPFLAGS)` has no effect on a program being build by any of the common distros, from Debian to Yocto or what have you.

Furthermore, when preprocessor flags are passed, they appear in `CFLAGS`. So even if you support `CPPFLAGS` (whether by way of using built-in GNU Make rules, or imitating them) you cannot assume that only `CPPFLAGS` will contain flags for preprocessing.

Separation of preprocessor flags from `CFLAGS` is unnecessary because:

- There is a way to run `gcc` to do preprocessing only. That `gcc` command can still take compiler options not related to preprocessing.
- Conversely, the stand-alone GNU `cpp` is tolerant to compiler options, such as `-W` warnings that do not pertain to preprocessing and even code generation options like `-fstrict-aliasing` and the linker-pass through like `-Wl,--whatever`.

So generally speaking, build systems that need to call the stand-alone preprocessor for whatever reason on C code can just pass it `$(CFLAGS)`.

It's easy enough for the application developers to write GNU Make code to separate preprocessor flags out of `$(CFLAGS)`:

```
cpp_only_flags := $(foreach arg,                        \
                     $(CFLAGS),                         \
                     $(or $(filter -D%,$(arg)),         \
                          $(filter -U%,$(arg)),         \
                          $(filter -I%,$(arg)),         \
                          $(filter -iquote%,$(arg)),    \
                          $(filter -W%,$(arg)),         \
                          $(filter -M%,$(arg))))        \
                          $(CPPFLAGS) # also pull this in

all:
    @echo cpp_only_flags == $(cpp_only_flags)
```

Demo:

```
$ make CFLAGS="-Wall -I/path/to/include -W -UMAC -DFOO=bar -o foo.o -lm"
cpp_only_flags == -Wall -I/path/to/include -W -UMAC -DFOO=bar
```

In the case of the GNU compiler and preprocessor, this is probably unnnecessary; but it illustrates a technique that could be used for non-GNU compilers and preprocessors, in a build system based on GNU Make.

Nonetheless, interpolating `$(CPPFLAGS)` into build rules seems like a good idea just because GNU Make does it in its own rules.

Also, as mentioned already, GNU Make pulls in the same `CPPFLAGS` variable into build rules for different languages, whereas `CFLAGS` is only for C. For instance if we have a project that has preprocessed Fortran, as well as C, then `CPPFLAGS` will act globally across the C and Fortran, which could be something useful in that kind of project.

In summary,

- there is no harm in supporting `CPPFLAGS`;
- some distros out there use it (Gentoo?) which makes it a good idea to support it in your Makefile, similarly to the GNU Make built-in recipes;
- it's probably a bad idea to advertise the variable as something that should be used;
- when building other people's projects, probably avoid relying on `CPPFLAGS` to do anything that can be done with `CFLAGS`.

Comment: "As an application developer writing a `Makefile`, you cannot rely on the existence of `CPPFLAGS`" -- surely you can add it to your installation instructions? Makefiles can have so many quirks that you pretty much always need to double-check the instructions when building or packaging an unfamiliar program.

Comment: @shadowtalker If you're writing a project that you hope is packaged into distros, you should avoid unusual build instructions and stick to conventions. You will be handed `CFLAGS` for sure. If you need to call `cpp` separately from the compiler for whatever reason, you should pull the `cpp`-specific flags from `CFLAGS` yourself. It's not reasonable to ask the the distro maintainer to do that. They will likely have to write code in order to do that. If your program goes into seven distros, seven people will do it differently, and two will get it wrong in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I installed httpd on Ubuntu 18.04 using the CPPFLAGS variable for the -DLINUX flag. When run, CPPFLAGS scans the code from top to bottom, file by file, looking for directives before compiling, and will not be extended by other meaningful things like size optimization, flags that do not increase the size of the output file; under the type of processor; to reduce the size of the code and speed up the program; disable all variables except case.  The only difference between CPPFLAGS and CFLAGS is that CFLAGS can be set to specify additional switches to be passed to the compiler. That is, the CFLAGS environment variable creates a directory in the installation path (eg `CFLAGS=-i/opt/include`) to add debugging information to the executable target's path: include general alarm messages; turning off alarm information; independent location generation; display compiler driver, preprocessor, compiler version number.

Standard way to set CPPFLAGS:

```
sudo ./configure --enable-unixd=DLINUX #for example
```

list of some known variables:

```
CPPFLAGS - is the variable name for flags to the C preprocessor.
CXXFLAGS - is the standard variable name for flags to the C++ compiler.
CFLAGS is - the standard name for a variable with compilation flags.
LDFLAGS - should be used for search flags/paths (-L) - i.e. -L/usr/lib (/usr/lib are library binaries).
LDLIBS - for linking libraries.
```