# CFLAGS, CCFLAGS, CXXFLAGS - what exactly do these variables control?

Tags: gcc, naming-conventions, makefile

I am using GNU make to compile my C++ code, and I would like to understand how to make my compilations customizable.

I read in different places that `CFLAGS`, `CCFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` are used for this purpose. So how should i use them? If I have additional command-line arguments to the compiler, should I append them to `CFLAGS` or prepend them? Is there a common practice?

Why the three different variables? I suppose the C compiler should get `CFLAGS` and `CCFLAGS`, while the C++ compiler should get `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`—did I get it right?

Is the human user supposed to set these variables at all? Do any automatic tools (`automake`, `autoconf`, etc) set them? The Linux system that I am supposed to use doesn't define any of these variables—is this typical?

Currently my Makefile looks like this, and I feel it's a bit dirty:

```
ifdef code_coverage
    GCOV_FLAG := -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
else
    GCOV_FLAG :=
endif

WFLAGS := -Wall

INC_FLAGS := -Istuff -Imore_stuff -Ietc

CCFLAGSINT := -O3 $(WFLAGS) $(INC_FLAGS) $(CCFLAGS)

... (somewhere in the makefile, the command-line for compilation looks like this)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGSINT) -c $< -o $@

... (somewhere in the makefile, the command-line for linking looks like this)
    $(CC) $(GCOV_FLAG) $(CCFLAGSINT) $(OBJLIST) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

I am pretty sure there are no bugs here; the Makefile works very well. But is there anything that goes against conventions (like `CCFLAGSINT`—should I just overwrite `CCFLAGS` instead? Or `CXXFLAGS`? FUD!)

Sorry for so many questions; you will obviously not answer them all, but I hope the answers will help me understand the general idea behind these settings.

Comment: Is it fair to say, based on these answers, that these environmental variables don't change / are not used by the `gcc` or `clang` compilers *themselves*?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

As you noticed, these are Makefile {macros or variables}, not compiler options. They implement a set of conventions. (Macros is an old name for them, still used by some. GNU make doc calls them variables.)

The only reason that the names matter is the default make rules, visible via `make -p`, which use some of them.

If you write all your own rules, you get to pick all your own macro names.

In a vanilla gnu make, there's no such thing as CCFLAGS. There are `CFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS`, and `CXXFLAGS`. `CFLAGS` for the C compiler, `CXXFLAGS` for C++, and `CPPFLAGS` for both.

Why is `CPPFLAGS` in both? Conventionally, it's the home of preprocessor flags (`-D`, `-U`) and both c and c++ use them. Now, the assumption that everyone *wants* the same define environment for c and c++ is perhaps questionable, but traditional.

---

P.S. As noted by [James Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73046/james-moore), some projects use CPPFLAGS for flags to the C++ compiler, not flags to the C preprocessor. The Android NDK, for one huge example.

Comment: I downvoted you for being slightly wrong, but you're close enough to right that it's not worth me making an entirely separate answer. `$(CPPFLAGS)` are flags for the preprocessor. The fact that they're used in the invocations of `$(CC)` and `$(CXX)` is incidental. Also, they're Makefile variables, not macros.

Comment: @Jack: GNU Make calls them variables; several other sources, including the Single Unix Specification's description of _make_, call them macros.  Same thing.

Comment: @Jack in 1982 when I met make they called them macros.

Comment: aaand I've thoroughly been taken to school. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Jack, no, no no. I'm not trying to school you, just to explain from whence came my particular view. In fact, watch for an edit ...

Comment: @bmargulies: I'm not annoyed or offeneded. I reversed my downvote a couple of days ago. Thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: @JackKelly I deeply wish you were right.  Unfortunately, there isn't a single convention; you'll find projects that believe CPPFLAGS is for flags to the C++ compiler, not flags to the C preprocessor.  The Android NDK, for one huge example.

Comment: An old, but good, response.  Just to make one thing clear: `CPPFLAGS` wasn't invented so that C and C++ compilers could share preprocessor variables.  Indeed, `CPPFLAGS` _predates_ C++ compilers being in common use.  `CPPFLAGS` is a separate variable because various other tools that need to run the preprocessor on your code also want access to the preprocessor flags.  For example, linting tools, tags tools, dependency-generation tools, etc.

Answer (score 29):

According to the `GNU make` manual:

> CFLAGS:  Extra flags to give to the C compiler.
>   CXXFLAGS:  Extra flags to give to the C++ compiler.
>   CPPFLAGS: Extra flags to give to the C preprocessor and programs that use it (the C and Fortran compilers).

src: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-CFLAGS
note: PP stands for PreProcessor (and not Plus Plus), i.e.

> CPP: Program for running the C preprocessor, with results to standard output; default ‘$(CC) -E’.

These variables are used by the implicit rules of `make`

> Compiling C programs
>   n.o is made automatically from n.c with a recipe of the form
>   ‘$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c’.
>
> Compiling C++ programs
>   n.o is made automatically from n.cc, n.cpp, or n.C with a recipe of the form
>   ‘$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c’.
>   We encourage you to use the suffix ‘.cc’ for C++ source files instead of ‘.C’.

src: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules

Answer (score 10):

**Minimal example**

And just to make what [Mizux said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52179619/895245) as a minimal example:

main_c.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("hello");
}
```

main_cpp.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}
```

Then, without any `Makefile`:

```
make CFLAGS='-g -O3' \
     CXXFLAGS='-ggdb3 -O0' \
     CPPFLAGS='-DX=1 -DY=2' \
     CCFLAGS='--asdf' \
     main_c \
     main_cpp
```

runs:

```
cc -g -O3 -DX=1 -DY=2   main_c.c   -o main_c
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -DX=1 -DY=2   main_cpp.cpp   -o main_cpp
```

So we understand that:

- `make` had implicit rules to make `main_c` and `main_cpp` from `main_c.c` and `main_cpp.cpp`
- CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS were used as part of the implicit rule for `.c` compilation
- CXXFLAGS and CPPFLAGS were used as part of the implicit rule for `.cpp` compilation
- CCFLAGS is not used.

  BTW, the [SCons build system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCons) for example [uses CCFLAGS for flags that are common to C and C++](https://scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-user/a4774.html), which is a convention I sometimes follow on my custom make rules.

Those variables are only used in make's implicit rules automatically: if compilation had used our own explicit rules, then we would have to explicitly use those variables as in:

```
main_c: main_c.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

main_cpp: main_c.c
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

to achieve a similar affect to the implicit rules.

We could also name those variables however we want: but since Make already treats them magically in the implicit rules, those make good name choices.

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04, GNU Make 4.1.

Related: [CFLAGS vs CPPFLAGS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754966/cflags-vs-cppflags)

Answer (score 1):

This is an addition to all the existing answers, which mostly describe how these `make` variables affect the compilation process. In this answer, I describe a suggested way to use these variables, and any surrounding considerations. It is partly inspired by [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51806613/509868).

> How should I use them? Should I append or prepend?

Compilation flags are of two types:

1. Those which are required to make the compilation work (example: `-I`, which tells  the compiler where to find h-files).
2. Those which customize the compilation (example: `-O`, optimization level).

Only type 2 (customization) should go into `CCFLAGS`, and if the user specifies them, they should override whatever is defined in the `Makefile`. Use `?=` syntax for that in your `Makefile`:

```
CCFLAGS ?= -O3
```

Type 1 settings should go into a new made-up variable, which should aggregate them all, and also include the standard variables, like `CCFLAGS`:

```
INC_FLAGS := -Istuff -Imore_stuff -Ietc

CCFLAGS_INTERNAL := $(INC_FLAGS) $(CCFLAGS)
```

> Is there a common practice?

No, it doesn't seem so. Stuff I described above is one option, which looks good, but it's not standard.

> Is the human user supposed to set these variables at all? The linux system that I use doesn't define any of these variables - is this typical?

Yes, these are for specifying options using the command line. The environment variables usually don't exist.

> Is there anything that goes against conventions? (like CCFLAGSINT - should I just overwrite CCFLAGS instead? Or CXXFLAGS? FUD!)

No, the idea of this `Makefile` is correct: append `CCFLAGS` and other flags to the compiler's command-line; don't update `CCFLAGS`.