# WebAssembly | error: invalid argument '-std=c++11' not allowed with 'C/ObjC'

Tags: c++, c, c++11, emscripten, webassembly

I have a project containing both C++ and C files which I am compiling from the command line with Emscripten using this command:

```
emcc -s WASM=1 -o output.html -s "EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall', 'cwrap', 'Pointer_stringify']" -s ASSERTIONS=1 -O1 -O2 -O3 -std=c++11 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1  file1.cpp file2.c
```

I need to use c++11 for this to work but because some of the files are in C it gives this error:

```
error: invalid argument '-std=c++11' not allowed with 'C/ObjC'
```

Is there some way I can tell the compiler to only use c++11 for the C++ files but not the C files?

Comment: You can compile and link separately, i.e. compile `file1.cpp` and `file2.c` and then link `file1.o` and `file2.o`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can [use the environment variable `CXXFLAGS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541946/cflags-ccflags-cxxflags-what-exactly-do-these-variables-control) to do so.

In practice, in your case, you should split the command line in two: one for C++ files, one for C files. This is what we usually find in Makefiles.