# Enabeling C++ 11 support in my makefile using CXXFLAGS

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, compilation

I'm trying to compile my program on my School's server but need to enabel C++ 11 in order to get my program to compile. I'm not sure if I how to implement the g++ -std=c++11 *.cpp *.h -o programName that I used when compiling from my the terminal.

This is my makefile:

```
all, Project4, Project4.exe: Character.o Barbarian.o BlueMen.o Vampire.o 
Medusa.o HarryPotter.o LinkedList.o Queue.o Stack.o main.o
g++ main.o Character.o Barbarian.o BlueMen.o Vampire.o Medusa.o 
HarryPotter.o LinkedList.o Queue.o Stack.o -o Projec4

Character.o: Character.cpp Character.h
    g++ -c Character.cpp

Barbarian.o: Barbarian.cpp Barbarian.h
    g++ -c Barbarian.cpp

BlueMen.o: BlueMen.cpp BlueMen.h
    g++ -c BlueMen.cpp

Vampire.o: Vampire.cpp Vampire.h
    g++ -c Vampire.cpp

Medusa.o: Medusa.cpp Medusa.h
    g++ -c Medusa.cpp

HarryPotter.o: HarryPotter.cpp HarryPotter.h
    g++ -c HarryPotter.cpp

LinkedList.o: LinkedList.cpp LinkedList.h
    g++ -c LinkedList.cpp

Queue.o: Queue.cpp Queue.h
    g++ -c Queue.cpp

Stack.o: Stack.cpp Stack.h
    g++ -c Stack.cpp

main.o: main.cpp Character.h Barbarian.h BlueMen.h Vampire.h Medusa.h 
HarryPotter.h LinkedList.h Queue.h Stack.h
    g++ -c main.cpp

clean:
    -rm *.o
```

Comment: As hinted in your title, maybe use `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: check here, it's explained: http://makepp.sourceforge.net/1.19/makepp_tutorial.html

Comment: Except for implicit commands, `CXXFLAGS` won't help you unless you put in in your compile commands.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the necessary compile parameter to the makefile rules:

```
all, Project4, Project4.exe: Character.o Barbarian.o BlueMen.o Vampire.o 
Medusa.o HarryPotter.o LinkedList.o Queue.o Stack.o main.o
g++ main.o Character.o Barbarian.o BlueMen.o Vampire.o Medusa.o 
HarryPotter.o LinkedList.o Queue.o Stack.o -std=c++11 -o Projec4

Character.o: Character.cpp Character.h
    g++ -c -std=c++11 Character.cpp

Barbarian.o: Barbarian.cpp Barbarian.h
    g++ -c -std=c++11 Barbarian.cpp

BlueMen.o: BlueMen.cpp BlueMen.h
    g++ -c -std=c++11 BlueMen.cpp

Vampire.o: Vampire.cpp Vampire.h
    g++ -c -std=c++11 Vampire.cpp

Medusa.o: Medusa.cpp Medusa.h
    g++ -c -std=c++11 Medusa.cpp

HarryPotter.o: HarryPotter.cpp HarryPotter.h
    g++ -c -std=c++11 HarryPotter.cpp

LinkedList.o: LinkedList.cpp LinkedList.h
    g++ -c -std=c++11 LinkedList.cpp

Queue.o: Queue.cpp Queue.h
    g++ -c -std=c++11 Queue.cpp

Stack.o: Stack.cpp Stack.h
    g++ -c -std=c++11 Stack.cpp

main.o: main.cpp Character.h Barbarian.h BlueMen.h Vampire.h Medusa.h 
HarryPotter.h LinkedList.h Queue.h Stack.h
    g++ -c -std=c++11 main.cpp

clean:
    -rm *.o
```

For maintainability you could also add a makefile-variable containing all the compiler-flags necessary:

```
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11

all, Project4, Project4.exe: Character.o Barbarian.o BlueMen.o Vampire.o 
Medusa.o HarryPotter.o LinkedList.o Queue.o Stack.o main.o
g++ main.o Character.o Barbarian.o BlueMen.o Vampire.o Medusa.o 
HarryPotter.o LinkedList.o Queue.o Stack.o $(CXXFLAGS) -o Projec4

Character.o: Character.cpp Character.h
    g++ -c $(CXXFLAGS) Character.cpp

Barbarian.o: Barbarian.cpp Barbarian.h
    g++ -c $(CXXFLAGS) Barbarian.cpp

BlueMen.o: BlueMen.cpp BlueMen.h
    g++ -c $(CXXFLAGS) BlueMen.cpp

Vampire.o: Vampire.cpp Vampire.h
    g++ -c $(CXXFLAGS) Vampire.cpp

Medusa.o: Medusa.cpp Medusa.h
    g++ -c $(CXXFLAGS) Medusa.cpp

HarryPotter.o: HarryPotter.cpp HarryPotter.h
    g++ -c $(CXXFLAGS) HarryPotter.cpp

LinkedList.o: LinkedList.cpp LinkedList.h
    g++ -c $(CXXFLAGS) LinkedList.cpp

Queue.o: Queue.cpp Queue.h
    g++ -c $(CXXFLAGS) Queue.cpp

Stack.o: Stack.cpp Stack.h
    g++ -c $(CXXFLAGS) Stack.cpp

main.o: main.cpp Character.h Barbarian.h BlueMen.h Vampire.h Medusa.h 
HarryPotter.h LinkedList.h Queue.h Stack.h
    g++ -c $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp

clean:
    -rm *.o
```

Further information about customizing your makefile can be found here: [CFLAGS, CCFLAGS, CXXFLAGS - what exactly do these variables control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541946/cflags-ccflags-cxxflags-what-exactly-do-these-variables-control)