# Where to put things (CFLAGS or CXXFLAGS) on Makefile?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, makefile, gnu-make

First the `Makefile` here had

```
CFLAGS   = -g -Wall -lm
```

I was playing with `C` that time. Now I'm on `C++` and I have to add `-I eigen`, quick google on it and found `CXXFLAGS` exist for the `C++` world, while `CFLAGS` exist for the `C` world. So I updated `Makefile` to

```
CFLAGS   = -g -Wall -lm
CXXFLAGS = -I eigen
```

Then I found https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GCC_optimization, and was inspired to updated it again

```
CFLAGS   = -g -Wall -lm
CXXFLAGS = ${CFLAGS} -I eigen
```

The complete thing:

```
CC       = g++
CFLAGS   = -g -Wall -lm
CXXFLAGS = ${CFLAGS} -I eigen
OBJS     = main.o multiply.o 
PROGRAM  = multitply
$(PROGRAM): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROGRAM)
```

Should I add `-I eigen` to `CXXFLAGS` or `CFLAGS`?

Also noticed the existence of `CPPFLAGS`.

Should I change to `$(CC) $(OBJS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(PROGRAM)` 
or to `$(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(PROGRAM)`?

Should I change to `$(PROGRAM): $(OBJS) *.h`,  so it rebuilds whenever `.h` files get changes?

Any other improvements to it?

Comment: Defining `CXXFLAGS` in terms of `CFLAGS` is probably not a good idea. I usually interpret `CFLAGS` to refer to flags for the C compiler specifically, and `CXXFLAGS` for the flags to the C++ compiler. If you don't have mixed languages in your project then you don't need the C version of the flags at all.

Comment: Which files do you have? C or C++ files?

Comment: "Now I'm on `C++`".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CFLAGS, CCFLAGS, CXXFLAGS - what exactly do these variables control?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5541946/608639) Also see [GNU Coding Standards - Makefile Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Makefile-Conventions.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use `CFLAGS` when compiling C files and `CXXFLAGS` when compiling C++ files. Besides `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` you are perhaps missing another relevant variable here: **`CPPFLAGS`**.

> Should I add `-I eigen` to `CXXFLAGS` or `CFLAGS`?

`CPPFLAGS` is typically used for providing options related to the preprocessor.
I would use this variable for specifying include directories:

```
CPPFLAGS = -I eigen
```

Another interesting variable, which is useful for providing libraries, would be **`LDLIBS`**. You could take advantage of it for passing `-lm`:

```
LDLIBS = -lm
```

---

> Should I change to `$(PROGRAM): $(OBJS) *.h`, so it rebuilds whenever `.h` files get changes?

The approach I would recommend is to add prerequisites for the header files to the corresponding object files by writing rules without recipe, for example:

```
main.o: main.h multiply.h ...
multiply.o: multiply.h ...
```

Besides, `*` won't do what you expect to do, i.e., it is not a wildcard in that context. Place those lines at the end of the Makefile, so that they don't replace the default target.

---

The Makefile could be something like:

```
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall
CPPFLAGS = -I eigen
LDLIBS   = -lm
OBJS     = main.o multiply.o 
PROGRAM  = multitply

$(PROGRAM): $(OBJS)
   $(CXX) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

No need for repeating `$(PROGRAM)` and `$(OBJS)` in the recipe, you can simply use the automatic variables `$@` and `$^`, respectively.