# How to update the __cplusplus value

Tags: c++, makefile, c++17

in my project I would like to use the  header on a raspberry pi zero. However, inside the header, this statement evaluates to false:

`#if __cplusplus >= 201703L`
I checked the value and it is indeed just at `201402L`

g++ --version returns `g++ (Raspbian 10.2.1-6+rpi1) 10.2.1 20210110`
and in my Makefile I specified:
`CXXFLAGS := -std=c++17 -Wall`.

`g++ -x c++ -std=c++17 -dM -E - </dev/null | less` lists the value for `#define __cplusplus 201703L`

So I quite don't understand, why the __cplusplus value is still at the value for c++14.
Is there a way to update/change/set this macro?

Edit: My Makefile

```
SOURCES := $(shell find ./src -name '*.cpp')
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++17 -Wall

default: 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -O3 -pthread -o main $(SOURCES) -lpigpio -lrt

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm main
```

Output, when I run `make`

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -O3 -pthread -o main <all the cpp files here> -lpigpio -lrt
```

Comment: did you try to set the [CXX_STANDARD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541946/cflags-ccflags-cxxflags-what-exactly-do-these-variables-control)?

Comment: This macro is set by your compiler. You could, of course, do `undef` and then `define` before including the header, but that would be highly counter productive. It is much more likely that your makefile has a problem.

Comment: You have confirmed your compiler supports C++17, but it seems your project is compiling in C++14. How have you confirmed that your makefile is written correctly? What is the g++ command line when you use the makefile?

Comment: Can't reproduce here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Yoaqr6cv1 Show your makefile.

Comment: Your manually-executed command explicitly specified `-std=c++17`, but what about whatever build system you're using to compile the real code?

Comment: @VLL just edited my post and added the makefile and the output

Comment: @HolyBlackCat running the same Code in my main also produces `201703` as Output, thats a bit weird now. The macro inside the <filesystem> header still evaluates to false

Comment: How do you know what it evaluates to?