# How can I pass a macro definition from "make" command line arguments (-D) to C source code?

Tags: c, macros, makefile

I usually pass macro definitions from "make command line" to a "makefile" using the option:
[-D](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1)name=value. The definition is accessible inside the makefile.

I also pass macro definitions from the "makefile" to the "source code" using the similar compiler option:
-Dname=value (supported in many compilers). This definition is accessible in the source code.

Now I need to allow the user of my makefile to be able to pass arbitrary macro definitions from the "make.exe commandline" to "source code" right away, without having to change anything in the makefile.

So the user can type:

```
make -f mymakefile.mk -SOMEOPTION var=5
```

Then directly the code in *main.c* can see `var`:

```c
int main()
{
  int i = var;
}
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Call the `make` command this way:

```
make CFLAGS=-Dvar=42
```

And be sure to use `$(CFLAGS)` in your compile command in the Makefile. As @jørgensen mentioned, putting the variable assignment after the `make` command will override the `CFLAGS` value already defined in the Makefile.

Alternatively, you could set `-Dvar=42` in another variable than `CFLAGS` and then reuse this variable in `CFLAGS` to avoid completely overriding `CFLAGS`.

Comment: ... and @MemoryLeaks should be cautious and not override `CGLAGS` in his Makefile, e.g. always use `CGLAGS = $(CGLAGS) -Wall`.

Comment: You cannot use "CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -Wall"; this would be a recursive definition and make does not allow this.  You could use "CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -Wall", or "CFLAGS += -Wall", but those won't work either because an assignment on the command line has a higher precedence.  You could use "override CFLAGS += -Wall", but generally we recommend you just choose different variables internally.  The GNU Coding Standards require CFLAGS etc. be left for the user, and makefiles choose another variable, like "local_CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -Wall".

Comment: Just to add to @MadScientist note, the [GNU Coding Standards also state](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command-Variables.html#Command-Variables) that `$(CFLAGS)` should come last, so that any options specified by a user will override anything the Makefile sets internally. That would mean using e.g. `local_CFLAGS = -Wall $(CFLAGS)`. Conversely, if there's something you really want to take precedence, put it after `$(CFLAGS)`, as in @MadScientist comment.

Comment: How to set multiple macros by this?

Comment: @WoodyHuang for example `CFLAGS="-Dvar1=42 -Dvar2=314"`

Comment: `CPPFLAGS` might represent a better fit than `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53527858/2278206

Comment: This doesn't work if you call make again and the source code hasn't changed. So if you want to toggle a macro value, is the only way to update the modification time on a piece of source code so make runs again?

Comment: @WoodyHuang Multiple flags: `CFLAGS+=-Dvar1=42 CFLAGS+=-Dvar2=314`

Answer (score 19):

I would like to mention the predefined variable `CPPFLAGS`.
It might represent a better fit than `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS`, since [it is described by the *GNU Make* manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-CPPFLAGS) as:

> Extra flags to give to the C preprocessor and programs that use it
> (the C and Fortran compilers).

#### Examples of built-in implicit rules that use `CPPFLAGS`

- `n.o` is made automatically from `n.c` with a recipe of the form:

  `$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c`
- `n.o` is made automatically from `n.cc`, `n.cpp`, or `n.C` with a recipe of the form:

  `$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c`

One would use the command `make CPPFLAGS=-Dvar=123` to define the desired macro.

#### More information

- [Variables Used by Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html)
- [Catalogue of Built-In Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules)

Comment: "CPP" in "`CPPFLAGS`" for ***[C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)***, not C++(?).

Comment: Related: *[CFLAGS vs CPPFLAGS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754966/cflags-vs-cppflags)*

Comment: And *[CFLAGS, CCFLAGS, CXXFLAGS - what exactly do these variables control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541946/cflags-ccflags-cxxflags-what-exactly-do-these-variables-control)* and *[Difference between CPPFLAGS and CXXFLAGS in GNU Make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495598/difference-between-cppflags-and-cxxflags-in-gnu-make)*.

Answer (score 15):

Just use a specific variable for that.

```
$ cat Makefile 
all:
    echo foo | gcc $(USER_DEFINES) -E -xc - 

$ make USER_DEFINES="-Dfoo=one"
echo foo | gcc -Dfoo=one -E -xc - 
...
one

$ make USER_DEFINES="-Dfoo=bar"
echo foo | gcc -Dfoo=bar -E -xc - 
...
bar

$ make 
echo foo | gcc  -E -xc - 
...
foo
```

Answer (score 10):

Call 'make' *this* way:

```
make CFLAGS=-Dvar=42
```

because you do want to override your Makefile's CFLAGS, and not just the environment (which has a lower priority with regard to Makefile variables).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat x.mak
all:
    echo $(OPTION)
$ make -f x.mak 'OPTION=-DPASSTOC=42'
echo -DPASSTOC=42
-DPASSTOC=42
```

Answer (score -3):

Find the C file and Makefile implementation in below to meet your requirements

foo.c

```
 main ()
    {
        int a = MAKE_DEFINE;
        printf ("MAKE_DEFINE value:%d\n", a);
    }
```

Makefile

```
all:
    gcc -DMAKE_DEFINE=11 foo.c
```

Comment: the question is to pass arbitrary definitions from the make commandline directly to C source code "without changing the makefile". So I wanted to change my makefile once, to allow for those arbitrary definitions to be made.

Comment: Doesn't work for make. That is make -DMAKE_DEFINE=11 says invalid option.