# How can a macro definition be passed as an argument to make?

Tags: c, makefile, macros, gnu-make

I wish to define a C macro by passing it as an argument to `make`, which is called from the command-line.

Background: I want the directive `#define ENABLE_OPT 1` to be included in my C source code when a certain build option is chosen. Thus, I want this to be done via the `make` command-line instead of modifying the source code *or* the makefile.

How can this be achieved? I find that `make -DENABLE_OPT=1 -f Makefile` throws errors that 'E', 'N' etc. are invalid arguments to make.

Comment: make CFLAGS="-DENABLE_OPT=1"

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052792/how-to-pass-macro-definition-from-make-command-line-arguments-d-to-c-source

Comment: Thank you. I have only LOCAL_CFLAGS defined in the makefile, so this wouldn't override anything. Sounds good!

Comment: Even if CFLAGS is defined before, you can use `CFLAGS+=` to add the macro to CFLAGS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `--eval`, which will evaluate the string as a makefile statement:

```
make --eval="FLAGS+= -D ENABLE_OPT=1"
```

The make variable FLAGS is then used as a compiler argument to compile the code.