# 'make' equivalent of -D flag as in gcc

Tags: c, linux, makefile

My C code has various files having statements that I want to execute only if a macro is defined. I have two files each having the following code:

```
#ifdef SOME_MACRO
printf("macro defined\n");
#else
printf("macro undefined");
#endif
```

My Makefile contains:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r )/build M=$(PWD) modules $(CFLAGS)
```

and I am calling make as:

```
make all CFLAGS=SOME_MACRO=10
```

When I execute the resulting program, I get 'macro undefined' indicating the macro is not being defined.

I have also tried calling it as:

```
make all CFLAGS=SOME_MACRO
```

which gives me:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `SOME_MACRO'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/X/Y/Z'
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

And also calling it as:

```
make all CFLAGS=-DSOME_MACRO=10
```

as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052792/how-to-pass-macro-definition-from-make-command-line-arguments-d-to-c-source) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39362327/how-can-a-macro-definition-be-passed-as-an-argument-to-make?noredirect=1&lq=1) but this is not working either.

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third form is correct (`make all CFLAGS=-DSOME_MACRO=10` or just `make all CFLAGS=-DSOME_MACRO`). But the make file that you are calling has to actually use that `CFLAGS` macro.

Make's [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) for compiling an executable or object c file will use `CFLAGS`, but we can't tell whether it is being invoked or overridden without seeing either the content of that makefile or the output from make.

The output from make should show the build commands. The implicit rule for making a `.o` from a `.c` file is `$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c` so you should see something like `cc -DSOME_MACRO=2 -DFOO=99  -c -o x.o x.c` given you compiling an object file, and similar if you compiling a executable.

Also make sure your cleaning you project properly `make clean`. And make sure the clean is actually recursive (i.e. cleans you "modules" project too)...

**Edit:** Oh yeah ... as @nneonneo's answer points out you also have an error in recursive the make call which is definitely an issue (I figured you were running the 2nd make command directly to debug the problem..). The above may still apply.

Comment: It is still not working, it might be the case that CFLAGS is getting overwritten. So is it possible to send the value in another variable? Anyway, I even tried doing CFLAGS+=-DSOME_MACRO=10 and it's not working.

Comment: @RaunaqKochar. That is possible. And yeah you can send any variable you like. CFLAGS is just a conventional name that is used by the implicit rules. So you could you go `make all XFLAGS=-DSOME_MACRO ...`, but you need to go find the compile rule in that makefile that builds the executable and stick `$(XFLAGS)` in the command line. Make sure you are doing a `make clean` first too!

Answer (score 1):

Your Makefile contains

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r )/build M=$(PWD) modules $(CFLAGS)
```

which will pass the value of the variable `CFLAGS` as `make` arguments. This is not what you want. Use `CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS)` instead:

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r )/build M=$(PWD) modules CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS)
```

to pass the `CFLAGS` along to the sub-make, then simply use `make CFLAGS=-DSOME_MACRO=10` to build.

Comment: Tried it, the errors are gone, but the piece of code when the macro isn't defined is still running. May be CFLAGS being overwritten is the reason. So is there any way to send some other variable to the make command inside the makefile?

Comment: The "correct" way would be to have [`export CFLAGS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables_002fRecursion) somewhere in the makefile, or as a target-specific variable for the rule in question. `make` should also be [`$(MAKE)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable).

Comment: @user657267 So how do I actually run the command? Say, I want to define SOME_MACRO? Should I still use the CFLAGS variable?

Comment: @RaunaqKochar variables set on the commandline are `export`ed by default into submakes, if you replace `make` with `$(MAKE)` in the recipes you should find it works as-is.

Comment: @user657267 I did $export CFLAGS=-DSOME_MACRO=10. And in the Makefile, my command is $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r )/build M=$(PWD) modules CFLAGS+=$(CFLAGS). The code still executes as if the macro isn't defined.

Comment: It looks like you're building a Linux kernel module. In that case, you should read the documentation on Kbuild before proceeding: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt