# How to pass argument from Makefile to a program?

Tags: c, makefile, directory, parameter-passing

I want to pass directory of Makefile to a function.

For example:

Makefile

`$(DIR) = makefile directory`

program

`int main(int argc,char argv[])
char directory = argv[1]`

How can I do that?

EDIT
Clarificaion. I want my app to work outside of the directory that i compiled it in.

Comment: It's not clear what you're triying to do. The makefile is usually used to compile the program, not run it.

Comment: makefile controls compilation while the arguments are passed at runtime. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Barmar I use a lot makefiles to build *and* run programs. Automated testing, for instance.

Comment: Your program doesn't compile: argv is a pointer to `char`...

Comment: @kebs That's why I said "usually". I think it's more likely the OP is confused than doing something like that.

Comment: @Barmar. Agree ! ;-)

Comment: It should be `char *argv[]` and `char *directory`.

Comment: I want my program to have acces to a file. The file is in the same directory as makefile

Comment: Why wouldn't your program work outside the directory it was compiled in?

Comment: Then the code you have tried to show is wrong. It will just fetch whatever is passed at runtime. If I get it, what you want is the directory of makefile to be**hardcoded** in your program. Seems strange to me... Why would you want to do that ? Could you edit question and give some details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a symbol at compile time is done with the -D option
(example is C++ but you can transpose to C easily). You can either only define the symbol, or give it a value (which is what you want here).

```
DIR=$(shell pwd)
mytarget: 
    @echo "DIRECTORY=$(DIR)"
    $(CXX) mysource.cpp -D"DIRECTORY=$(DIR)" -o mysource
```

Then, in your source file, the symbol `DIRECTORY` will hold the path. To check this, you need an additional trick (known as "double expansion"):

```
#define STR1(x)  #x
#define STR(x)  STR1(x)
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "directory is " << STR(DIRECTORY) << "\n";
}
```

You can check [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052792/), and [see here](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-d.html) about the D flag.

Comment: STR(DIRECTORY) return "1"

Comment: What do you mean ? What gets printed, exactly ? Add the echo line in makefile to see what the symbol holds".

Comment: @echo DIRECTORY prints "DIRECTORY"

Comment: @echo $(shell pwd) prints "/home/user/asq"

Comment: STR(DIRECTORY) in main() pints "1"

Comment: Oops, my fault, typo in there, corrected, see edit.

Comment: It works. Thank you!!

Comment: ok, glad, but... did somebody really downvote this ? Any comment, maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

In case the directory you need to pass is static (i.e. always the same) you can use the `-D` C compiler option:

```
cc -DDIRECTORY=/home/user/...
```

In your C source code you can then use `DIRECTORY`.