# How to remove unreachable conditional compilation blocks using clang lib?

Tags: c++, clang

I want to remove unreachable conditional blocks using clang lib. For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define X
#ifdef X
// code1
...
#elif
// code2
...
#endif
```

to

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define X
// code1
...
```

I guess that I can do this with the help of clang library but I'm unfamiliar with that.
Furthermore, how can I specify macro definitions by myself to control the output? Thank you for your reply.

Note that only conditional compilation statements are removed, other stuff like `#include <iostream>` and `#define X` should remain the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052792/how-to-pass-macro-definition-from-make-command-line-arguments-d-to-c-source

Comment: This is having to do with the preprocessor. The unreachable code would never be compiled anyways. You do not need to change anything if you don't want that code.

Comment: I think too many conditional compilation block that's unreachable makes the code harder to read, and that's why I want a tool with this function. I think a proper way to achieve this is to write a plugin of clang's preprocessor or ast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flag `-E` to only run the preprocessor and get the output of that step. Also you can use the flag `-D<stuff>` to define `<stuff>` (or `-D<stuff>=<thing>` to `#define <stuff> <thing>`).

You can see a short example here: https://godbolt.org/z/5j7bvE6ee

See also: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#preprocessor-flags

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I think it's not what I want. clang -E will also expand head like #include <iostream>, while I want the tool only deal with conditional compilation statements. I will update my example.