# What is "XX" in CXX in a cmake CMakeLists.txt file

Tags: c++, cmake

What is "XX" in CXX in a cmake CMakeLists.txt file.
What is its significance.

Why is it "XX" not PP against a CPP file ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`XX` stands for "++" (each `X` is like a "plus" rotated by 45°), `CXX` stands for "C++".

Why "`CXX`"?

- "`C++`" is not possible because of macro identifiers limitations (they can't contain a `+`);
- "`CPP`" (for "C Plus Plus") is usually *already used* to stand for "**C** **P**re**P**rocessor".

---

For example in a GNU Makefile you can define the following "variables":

- `CPPFLAGS` : extra flags for the C preprocessor (also used in C++).
- `CFLAGS`   : extra flags for the C compiler.
- `CXXFLAGS` : extra flags for the C++ compiler.

(Usually you will use `CPPFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` for a C project, and `CPPFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` for a C++ project.)

---

See also [Difference between CPPFLAGS and CXXFLAGS in GNU Make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495598/difference-between-cppflags-and-cxxflags-in-gnu-make) and [CFLAGS vs CPPFLAGS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754966/cflags-vs-cppflags).

Also related: [Correct C++ file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394328/correct-c-file-extension) (and duplicate links).

Answer (score 6):

Many filesystems do not allow `+` in filenames, which is why a number of naming conventions emerged for C++ source files over the years, inlcuding `.cpp`, `.cc` and `.cxx`.

CMake has a similar problem as its macro language is built around strings that are not allowed to hold special characters like `+`. This is simply a limitation to keep CMake's parser from becoming too complicated. So whenever they write `CXX`, what they really mean is just `C++`.