# How to specify a compiler in CMake?

Tags: cmake, iar

I would like to use the IAR compiler. I noticed CMake has already have a bunch of files about this compiler:

https://github.com/jevinskie/cmake/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/IAR.cmake

From what I read the common solution is to specify manually ALL the toolchain in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER iccarm)
set(CMAKE_CPP_COMPILER iccarm)
```

How CMake can link these definitions with `Modules/Compiler/IAR.cmake"?

I thought I would just have to do

```
include("Modules/Compiler/IAR.cmake")
```

What is the correct way to specify my IAR compiler?

When I do

```
cmake .
```

It still tries to use `gcc` instead of my IAR compiler. Why?

Comment: First of all, `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`, the language is **CXX**, not CPP

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986118/what-is-xx-in-cxx-in-a-cmake-cmakelists-txt-file for more details on @user7610's comment.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

To select a specific compiler, you have several solutions, as explained in [CMake wiki](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/FAQ#how-do-i-use-a-different-compiler):

**Method 1: use environment variables**

For C and C++, set the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables. This method is not guaranteed to work for all generators. (Specifically, if you are trying to set Xcode's `GCC_VERSION`, this method confuses Xcode.)
For example:

```
CC=gcc-4.2 CXX=/usr/bin/g++-4.2 cmake -G "Your Generator" path/to/your/source
```

**Method 2: use cmake -D**

Set the appropriate `CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER` variable(s) to a valid compiler name or full path on the command-line using `cmake -D`.
For example:

```
cmake -G "Your Generator" -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-4.2 -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-4.2 path/to/your/source
```

**Method 3 (avoid): use set()**

Set the appropriate `CMAKE_FOO_COMPILER` variable(s) to a valid compiler name or full path in a list file using `set()`. This must be done before any language is set (ie: before any `project()` or `enable_language()` command).
For example:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc-4.2")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++-4.2")

project("YourProjectName")
```

<s>The wiki doesn't provide reason why 3rd method should be avoided...</s>

The reason this method should be avoided is because it hardcodes paths and compilers which is something that is usually configured in a package manager such as conan. Conan allows you to detect which compiler is preferable on a given platform and forwards this to cmake. You would make things harder for everyone if you were to hardcode it. That's why option 2 is the preferred way do do it.

Comment: I don't understand why the third method should be avoided. With the first method, the user has to know the compiler he wants to use which shouldn't be the case because that project only builds with the specified compiler. With the second target the user has to write a very long line to configure the project. I rather prefer to put the command of method 2 in a bash file. This is very confusing to me.

Comment: 3d method has disadvantage that it **hardcodes** not only a compiler, but also a **path** to it. Or required from a user to have compiler under `PATH`. In any case user should be aware which compiler is used.

Comment: you can pass the name of the compiler, without setting the full path to it. In that case, it is searched in the PATH env variable

Comment: The CMake FAQ page has moved [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#how-do-i-use-a-different-compiler). Please edit.

Comment: For "path/to/your/source" are you referring to the CMake source directory or the gcc/g++ compiler source directory?

Comment: The CMake project source directory

Comment: Method 1 works for me, and note please delete CMakeCache.txt if any.

Comment: "I don't understand why the third method should be avoided. ... because that project only builds with the specified compiler."

If that's the case, then by all means, hard-code the compiler. As in the case from the answer, you are also hard-coding a specific compiler version, but if that's the only way your code compiles...

Either that, or fix your code. Cmake was made for c/c++. If you code to the std, your code should be expected to work on any compliant compiler. The user who compiles your code should be able to pick whatever compiler they want, that works best for their platform.

Comment: The statement from a dev from cmake explaining why they recommend avoiding the third method is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13089688/6691953

Comment: I _love_ the way with env. vars: no need to learn anything specific to cmake. Pure unix style.

Comment: I have a different use case that I'm not sure has been considered. I have an embedded project, so it's using an arm compiler. But i also have tests that I want to build which will run on my linux host. They're suggesting I need one compiler for the entire project. Even the accepted answer here says it's impossible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542971/using-cmake-with-multiple-compilers-for-the-same-language
I'm using the 3rd method to set the compiler to g++ for my test target, and that seems to work fine.

Comment: thanks for that, adding -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER to my Cmake command worked

Comment: The reason they say to Avoid it is that this hard-codes things into your CMakeLists.txt and therefore your build system.

Six of one, half dozen of another.  Making someone specify it out that specifically is...annoying.  Makes for problems with meta-build systems like Yocto, LTIB, etc.

It rather depends on YOUR use case there...and Kitware should explain themselves a LOT better than they do on some of this.

Answer (score 52):

I see more and more people who set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and other compiler-related variables in the `CMakeLists.txt` **after** the `project` call and wonder why this approach breaks sometimes.

### What happens actually

When CMake executes the `project()` call, it looks for a **default compiler executable** and determines the way for use it: default compiler flags, default linker flags, [compile features](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html), etc.

And CMake stores path to that default compiler executable in the `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` variable.

When one sets `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` variable **after** the `project()` call, this **only** changes the **compiler executable**: default flags, features all remains set for the *default compiler*.

**AS RESULT**: When the project is built, a build system calls the *project-specified* compiler *executable* but with *parameters* suitable for the *default compiler*.

As one could guess, this approach would work only when one replaces a default compiler with a **highly compatible** one. E.g. replacement of `gcc` with `clang` could work sometimes.

This approach will **never work** for replacement of `cl` compiler (used in Visual Studio) with `gcc` one. Nor this will work when replacing a *native* compiler with a *cross*-compiler.

### What to do

**Never** set a compiler in `CMakeLists.txt`.

If you want, e.g., to use `clang` instead of defaulted `gcc`, then either:

1. Pass `-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=<compiler>` to `cmake` when configure the project. That way CMake will use this compiler instead of default one and on the `project()` call it will adjust all flags for the specified compiler.
2. Set `CC` environment variable (`CXX` for C++ compiler). CMake checks this variable when selects a default compiler.
3. (Only in rare cases) Set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` variable **before** the `project()` call. This approach is similar to the first one, but makes the project less flexible.

### If the ways above do not work

If on setting `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` in the command line CMake errors that a compiler cannot "compile a simple project", then something wrong in your environment.. or you specify a compiler **incompatible** for chosen [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) or platform.

Examples:

- Visual Studio generators work with `cl` compiler but cannot work with `gcc`.
- A MinGW compiler usually requires [MinGW Makefiles](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/generator/MinGW%20Makefiles.html) generator.

Incompatible generator **cannot** be fixed in `CMakeLists.txt`. One need to pass the proper `-G` option to the `cmake` executable (or select the proper generator in CMake GUI).

### Cross-compiling

Cross-compiling usually requires setting [CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/variable/CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME.html) variable, and this setting should normally be done in the [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html). That *toolchain file* is also responsible for set a compiler.

Setting `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` in the `CMakeLists.txt` is almost **always an error**.

Comment: Good explanation for the question. BTW, I think this reveals an issue with the CMake language. You have to know how their algorithm works behind commands, i.e., it is does not follow a declarative rather than a procedural model.

Comment: What if I have to declare a complete custom command with all options? (Yes, this is the territory where `make` is easier. But CLion doesn't like `Makefile`s)

Comment: @Martin: You could use [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) and/or [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html). Not sure how this problem is related to the compiler's setting.

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a toolchain file, and use the CmakeForceCompiler module.

Here is an example toolchain file for bare-metal ARM development with IAR:

```
include(CMakeForceCompiler)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic) # Or name of your OS if you have one
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm) # Or whatever
set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING 1)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER iccarm) # Change the arm suffix if appropriate
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY) # Required to make the previous line work for a target that requires a custom linker file
```

The last line is necessary because CMake will try to compile a test program with the compiler to make sure it works and to get some version information from preprocessor defines. Without this line, CMake will use add_executable() for the test program, and you will get the error "The C compiler "XXX" is not able to compile a simple test program." This is because the test program fails to link, as it doesn't have your custom linker file (I'm assuming bare-metal development since this is what IAR is usually used for). This line tells CMake to use add_library() instead, which makes the test succeed without the linker file. Source of this workaround: [this CMake mailing list post](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2016-February/027871.html).

Then, assuming that your toolchain file is named iar-toolchain.cmake, invoke CMake like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=iar-toolchain.cmake .
```

Comment: How does the developer knows it has to write `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=iar-toolchain.cmake .`. In the traditional way with GNU Make, the developer sees a `Makefile` he hits `make`, that's simple. With CMake it looks a bit more complicated :(

Comment: You can make a wrapper script to call cmake. I have a script named build.sh at the root of all my projects

Comment: I get `The CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER macro is deprecated`

Comment: @nowox It’s true that it’s deprecated. I’ve been seeing these warnings for a while now but when I tried to change it I got the error: "The C compiler XXX is not able to compile a simple test program". At the time I couldn't find a solution so I've been living with the warning. Thanks to you I just looked again and found a workaround, see my edit!

Answer (score 5):

IAR Systems recently published a [basic CMake tutorial](https://github.com/IARSystems/cmake-tutorial) with examples under their GitHub profile.

I like the the idea of a generic toolchain file which works seamlessly for both Windows and Linux compilers using `find_program()`.

The following snippet will be used for when using `C` and can be used similarly for `CXX`:

```
# IAR C Compiler
find_program(CMAKE_C_COMPILER
  NAMES icc${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}
  PATHS ${TOOLKIT}
        "$ENV{ProgramFiles}/IAR Systems/*"
        "$ENV{ProgramFiles\(x86\)}/IAR Systems/*"
        /opt/iarsystems/bx${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}
  PATH_SUFFIXES bin ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}/bin
  REQUIRED )
```

For `ASM`, I initially got puzzled with the `NAMES` but then I realized that the toolchain file was made that way for working with old Assemblers shipped with XLINK:

```
find_program(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER
  NAMES iasm${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR} a${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}
  PATHS ${TOOLKIT}
        "$ENV{PROGRAMFILES}/IAR Systems/*"
        "$ENV{ProgramFiles\(x86\)}/IAR Systems/*"
        /opt/iarsystems/bx${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}
  PATH_SUFFIXES bin ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}/bin
  REQUIRED )
```

Also, take a look at the full [toolchain file](https://github.com/IARSystems/cmake-tutorial/blob/abbf75f35691e70fea17f5b1e21f177f6e7cbf90/examples/iar-toolchain.cmake). It will work automatically for "Arm" when the tools are installed on their default locations, otherwise it is just about updating the `TOOLKIT` variable and the compilers for all the supported languages should adjust automatically.

Answer (score 4):

You can call `cmake` like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=iccarm ...
```

or

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use your PC's standard compiler, you have to give CMake the path to the compiler. You do this via environment variables, a toolchain file or direct definitions in the CMake command line (see e.g. [CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (project): No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801638/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt30-project-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found)).

Putting the compiler's name/path into your CMakeLists.txt would stop your project from being cross-platform.

CMake does check for the compiler ids by compiling [special C/C++ files](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeCCompilerId.c.in). So no need to manually include from `Module/Compiler` or `Module/Platform`.

This will be automatically done by CMake based on its compiler and platform checks.

**References**

- [CMake: In which Order are Files parsed (Cache, Toolchain, …)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503631/cmake-in-which-order-are-files-parsed-cache-toolchain)
- [CMake GitLab Commit: Add support files for C, C++ and ASM for the IAR toolchain.](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/22fb73a0d6e27f0ecaf4e10705de204742427b31)

Comment: Do I still need to set `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` or there is another way? If I do `cmake .` it still tries to use `gcc`

Comment: @nowox You have to give CMake the path to the compiler. You do this via environment variables, a toolchain file or direct definitions in the CMake command line (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801638/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt30-project-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found)). Putting this into your `CMakeLists.txt` would stop your project from being cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

In Antwane's solution, we are to avoid using set(). A reason to **avoid** using `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/path/to/compiler")`, etc. is that the output of cmake is misleading, while the results are correct.

Consider linux where the default compiler is gcc (GNU 10.2.1), if I have CMakeLists.txt containing:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   "/path/to/llvm-16.0.0/bin/clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/path/to/llvm-16.0.0/bin/clang")
```

then with cmake 3.26.0, we get unexpected output:

```
cmake ../src
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.1
<snip>
```

but will use the specified clang compiler!

Removing the set() statements and using the other methods provides the expected result:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER="/path/to/llvm-16.0.0/bin/clang" -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/path/to/llvm-16.0.0/bin/clang" ../src
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 16.0.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 16.0.0
<snip>
```

Answer (score -2):

If your wanting to specify a compiler in cmake then just do ...

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++")
```

Options 1 is only used if you want to specify what compiler you want to use as default for everything that you might compile on your computer. And I don't even think it would work on windows.

Option 2 would be used if you only want to use a different temporarily.

Option 3 is used if that's the compiler that should be used for that particular project. Also option 3 would be the most cross compatible.