# Getting "undefined reference" errors when trying to build after linking library in Qt Creator on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, cmake, linker

I've seen similar questions like this asked here but none of them had any working answers and most of them were for Linux.

I'm making a Qt Widgets project in Qt Creator on Windows. I'm trying to link [rpclib](http://rpclib.net/). I've included the library by right clicking my project and using the "Add Library" wizard as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpulQ.png).

As long as the library is merely included and not used, it works fine. As soon as I'm trying to use a function from that library though, it gives me these [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3eyN.png).

Before including, I compiled the library as instructed in [rpclib](http://rpclib.net/) docs on Windows as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAyxM.png).

How do I get it to work?

Comment: Did you build `rpclib` with the same toolchain (mingw64)?

Comment: @mugiseyebrows I'm not quite sure, I just built it in powershell using CMake. How would I build it with mingw64? (Sorry for the stupid question, I'm not that experienced with C++)

Comment: try to specify compiler for cmake explicitly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933732/how-to-specify-a-compiler-in-cmake

Comment: This is a good point. msvc compiled c++ binaries will not be compatible with mingw.

Comment: ***if I can't find any working answers?*** You probably need to specify what you actually tried. Although if you compiled the library using Visual Studio Community that is likely your problem.

Comment: @mugiseyebrows Following up... I did figure out how to compile a MinGW makefile with cmake but when I build from that makefile I get a "librpc.a" file, which I don't think is compatible with Windows. I'm about to give up on this project, been trying to solve this for like 2 weeks.

Comment: @Leaves librpc.a is a static library, you can link it with your application, just add `LIBS += -L/path/to/librpc_lib_dir -lrpc` and `INCLUDEPATH += /path/to/librpc_include` to .pro file

Comment: An `.a` file is exactly what you want when using `mingw` as your compiler.

Comment: @drescherjm well now I'm just getting a bunch of error messages saying "undefined reference to __imp_... as seen here: https://i.imgur.com/wXVZ1X3.png

Comment: Probably need to link with `ws2_32.lib` which is part of `winapi` [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsasend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsasend) This is in addition to the libraries you already use.

Comment: @drescherjm already have winmm and ws2_32 linked so thats weird

Comment: The errors posted on the third-party resource went away. The question with a code and errors on third-party resources should be deleted.