# How to use cmake on windows with vs2019 and custom installed llvm?

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2019, llvm

I found someone mentioned to use such command line to use cmake with vs2019 and llvm toolset:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 2019" -T ClangCL
```

However, this would use the llvm version, which is 11.0 for now, was `installed by the visual studio instanller`.

I want to use a new version, thus 12.0, of llvm which I already installed somewhere else but I don't know how to make cmake and vs to use that.

---

UPDATE:

What I tried to set the compiler via command line:

```
E:\my_proj>cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64 -T "ClangCL" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang++.exe" .
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 11.0.0 with MSVC-like command-line
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 11.0.0 with MSVC-like command-line
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/clang-cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/Llvm/x64/bin/clang-cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
```

As you could see the cmake picked the clang from the vs installed location and ignored the command line.

Comment: What have you tried? Does setting `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` not work?

Comment: I tried ```set (CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang.exe")
set (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang++.exe")``` in the beginning of my CMakeLists.txt but that seems to be ignored.

Comment: @jayatubi: Have you tried **other approaches**, described in the answers to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933732/how-to-specify-a-compiler-in-cmake)? E.g. set `CC` and `CXX` environment variable, or pass `-D CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `-D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` options to `cmake`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev No. It always use the clang which was installed inside visual studio regardless what I set in the command line.

Comment: can you show us the output of "C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe" --version

Comment: @harry It's `12.0.1`. I just download it from llvm.org and fresh installed.

Comment: https://discourse.cmake.org/t/overriding-cmake-cxx-compiler-with-vs2017-on-windows-10/1311/2 hope this clears your question. BTW, I tried to install clang with VS installer and it installed 12.0.0.

Comment: @harry So does that mean with cmake the user could only select the toolset which provides by vs and can't use any external compilers?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you add a detailed answer then I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described below, setting CMAKE flags explicitly has no effect when using VS generator. Thus choosing the default compiler installed by Visual Studio installer.

> The VS generator produces .vcxproj files and uses MSBuild to actually
> drive the build. The values of CMAKE_{C,CXX}_COMPILER are computed
> automatically from the compiler MSBuild chooses so setting them has no
> effect.