# CMAKE clang variables

Tags: c, cmake, clang

I have this piece of code.

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Clang REQUIRED)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
```

I would like to set clang as C compiler, but if I use it like this, it uses clang from system and not from FIND_PACKAGE. FIND_PACKAGE should set some variables like CLANG_INCLUDE_DIRS. I need variable with path to clang, but I have not found name of that variable or other variables.
Where can I find it or what is the name of that variable ?

I use cmake 3.18

Comment: `find_package(clang` when you want to _build_ a program that _uses_ clang _library_, like a compiler plugin or some stuff from llvm. Just `set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER  /the/path/to/the/clang/you/want/to/use/clang)`. There is no "clang from find_package", or it's the same clang. I think.

Comment: @KamilCuk I want find_package to find clang and use that clang from find_package and i do not think this is how i can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I have done it with this snipped of code.
FIND_PACKAGE is not needed.

```
IF (NOT ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL "Clang")
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Set clang as C compiler")
ENDIF()
```

Answer (score 0):

By itself, `find_package(Clang)` searches only clang **libraries**, not a *compiler*. So it doesn't set any variable which points directly to the compiler.

The closest thing it sets is variable `LLVM_INSTALL_PREFIX`, which denotes the LLVM installation prefix. (This variable is set in [FindLLVM.cmake](https://github.com/KDE/kdevelop/blob/master/cmake/modules/FindLLVM.cmake) script, which is called by [FindClang.cmake](https://github.com/KDE/kdevelop/blob/master/cmake/modules/FindClang.cmake)).

So you could set the path to the C compiler with

```
# Instead of "Clang" package one could search "LLVM".
FIND_PACKAGE(Clang REQUIRED)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${LLVM_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/clang)
```

Make sure to place this setting **before** the `project()` call, as described in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45934279/3440745).