# CMake automatically adds -MD -MT and -MF options

Tags: cmake

Starting with cmake 3.20, a series of GNU-specific options are added to the compile lines, and I'm not sure why CMAKE_C_FLAGS does not remove them.

Prior to the release of cmake 3.20, those options were not added by default.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(TEST_SUITE)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER customCCompiler)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER customCXXCompiler)

add_compile_options(-fjust-one-option)
add_link_options(-ltest)

file(GLOB C_C_FILES "/a/path/to/*.c")
foreach(file ${C_C_FILES})
  cmake_path(GET file STEM LAST_ONLY title)
  add_executable(${title} ${file})
endforeach()
```

When ran with `cmake /path/to/CMakeLists.txt`, the config shows the following information:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/path
```

I get that in order to change the C compiler indentification from GNU to the customCCompiler, I would need to update the `cmake` command (which is currently ran without any other options other than the source directory of CMAkeLists.txt), what I don't get is why during compilation I am seeing `-MD -MT -MF` in the compile line:

```
    [ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/fenv.dir/a/path/fev.c.o
    customCCompiler -fjust-one-option -MD -MT CMakeFiles/fenv.dir/a/path/fev.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/fenv.dir/a/path/fev.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/fenv.dir/a/path/fev.c.o -c /a/path/fev.c
    warning: unsupported option -MD
```

Comment: Setting compiler **after** the `project()` call is wrong, see that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944545/3440745).

Comment: Oh, well, that explains a lot. Thank you so much for that link!