# CMake subproject cant find compiler

Tags: c++, cmake, git-submodules

I have a project with a structure as follows:

```
project
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── extern (git submodule)
│   └── mylib
│       ├── build
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       └── src
└── src
    └── main.c
```

`mylib` has its own build system and it's a git submodule. I want to be able to run `cmake --build build` in the top level project directory to build the file in `project/src`, build `mylib` and then link `mylib` to the binary built in `project`.

I use `add_subdirectory(extern/mylib)` to allow cmake to see and attempt to build the files in `extern/mylib`. However this does not work and I get the error:

```
CMake Error at extern/mylib/CMakeLists.txt:4 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
```

`riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc` is definitely in my PATH as shown by successfully running `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc` in the terminal and verifying that the directory shown by `which riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc` is inside my $PATH variable.

```
$ which riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc
/opt/riscv/bin/riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc
```

Is my approach wrong? How should I include this git submodule which my project is dependent on?

The same error is present for `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`.

Comment: `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc` is definitely not a default compiler selected by CMake. How do you specify that compiler? It smells like you have specified it by setting `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` variable in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` after the `project()` call...

Comment: I have, is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, this is wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944545/3440745.

Comment: You should be using a [cmake-toolchain](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) file in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Tsyvarev, I had incorrectly set CMAKE_C_COMPILER **after** the `project()` call in my CMakeLists.txt