# CMake and Flutter: Unable to Build and Run Flutter Application on Linux

Tags: c++, flutter, cmake, linux-mint, build-error

I am trying to build and run a Flutter application on Linux, but I am encountering issues with CMake. The application runs successfully on Google Chrome, but I'm having trouble getting it to work on Linux.

I have followed the steps provided in the Flutter documentation and made necessary modifications to the `CMakeLists.txt` file as per the suggestions I received. Here are the steps I have taken:

1. I installed Flutter and ensured that it is set up correctly, as I can run the application on Google Chrome using `flutter run -d chrome`.
2. I modified the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the `linux` directory of my Flutter project to set the C++ compiler and standard library explicitly. Here are the modifications I made:

   ```
   # Project-level configuration.
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
   project(runner LANGUAGES CXX)

   # Set the C++ compiler
   set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++")

   # Static link the standard C++ library
   set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -static-libstdc++")

   # Set C++17 standard
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")

   # Rest of the CMakeLists.txt content...
   ```
3. I also ran the following commands in the `linux` directory to build the project.

   ```
   cd linux
   rm -rf build
   mkdir build
   cd build
   cmake ..
   cmake --build .
   ```

   However, during the build process, I encounter the following error:

   ```
   CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:62 (message):
     The C++ compiler

       "/usr/bin/clang++"

     is not able to compile a simple test program.

     It fails with the following output:

       Change Dir: /home/farhan/App/flutter_application3/build/linux/x64/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

       Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/ninja cmTC_47048 && [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_47048.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
       [2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_47048
       FAILED: cmTC_47048 
       : && /usr/bin/clang++   CMakeFiles/cmTC_47048.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_47048   && :
       /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
       ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
   ```

I am unable to resolve this issue, and I am not sure what's causing the problem. I have verified that I have the necessary dependencies installed on my Linux system.

Could anyone please guide me on how to properly set up CMake and resolve this issue so that I can build and run my Flutter application on Linux successfully?

Comment: `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++")` why do you want to use `clang` compiler instead of `gcc`? `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++` - looks like it cannot find standard library, either not installed, or it tried to find it under wrong path.

Comment: I have tried the both gcc and clang.I don't know what to do further

Comment: Instead of **re-asking** [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76764942/cmake-error-cmake-cxx-compiler-not-set-even-after-explicitly-specifying-the-c), it is better to update the old one.

Comment: Note, that setting variable CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER **after** the `project()` call is plain **wrong**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944545/3440745.

Comment: "I have tried the both gcc and clang" - mmm OK, and what was the problem with gcc? Can you compile simple `g++ hello_world.cpp -o hello_world` ?

Comment: Yes i am able to compile hello_world.cpp