# compile_commands.json file with clangd lsp in neovim. Can't resolve " 'iostream' file not found " error even though .exe can be succesfully built

Tags: cmake, neovim, clangd

On Windows 10 in powershell

I am using g++ as a compiler with CMake and MinGW Makefiles

I am also using neovim (with the kickstarter config) and clangd lsp, installed from Mason

Also downloaded LLVM from https://releases.llvm.org/ . Not sure that's even necessary for clangd, or just for if I were to use clang++ instead of g++ .

Everywhere I look to explain this issue, I end up back here https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup which talks about using `compile_commands.json` which should be generated by cmake when I call this :

`cmake -S .\main\ -B .\main_build\ -G "MinGW Makefiles"`

Directory in my User\repos dir looks like this:

```
User\repos\c--_sampler\
- main\
-- CMakeLists.txt
-- main.cpp
- main_build\ (empty dir until I call 'cmake ...' command above)
-- CMakeFiles\
-- CMakeCache.txt
-- cmake_install.cmake
-- compile_commands.json
-- Makefile
```

The `compile_commands.json` does appear in /main_build/ , and I am able to run `cmake --build .` from within \main_build\ , resulting in the `main1_executable.exe` which I can then succesfully run and output 'Hello, World!' in powershell, all just as I would expect.

The problem is that despite all of this, when I `nvim main\main.cpp`, neovim (or perhaps better said, clangd lsp) gives the error " 'iostream' file not found ". I haven't the slightest idea where clangd decides what the path to the stdlib is, but I assume clangd (or neovim) must be missing a path to the stdlibc++ library.

That said, I do have `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` , which contains `libstdc++-6.dll`, added to path in env variables which I thought would be enough for clangd to use the library.

This is my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Proj1)
cmake_path(SET var1 "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe")
cmake_path(SET var2 "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe")
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${var1}" )
set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${var2}" )
set( CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON )
add_executable(main1_executable main.cpp)
```

This is my `compile_commands.json` file that cmake generates

```
[
{
  "directory": "C:/Users/User/repos/c--_sampler/main_build",
  "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe    -o CMakeFiles\\main1_executable.dir\\main.cpp.obj -c C:\\Users\\User\\repos\\c--_sampler\\main\\main.cpp",
  "file": "C:/Users/User/repos/c--_sampler/main/main.cpp",
  "output": "CMakeFiles/main1_executable.dir/main.cpp.obj"
}
]
```

I see many similar questions out there but none that seem to relevant my issue, or if they are, I am too dense to understand. I imagine there is something pretty simple I am missing here, but I've been struggling with this for the last couple days and at this point I'm just running in circles and my brain is turning to goo. Thanks in advance for any guidance you can give!

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but setting variable `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` after the `project()` call is wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944545/3440745

Answer (score 0):

This issue is usually solved by using `--query-driver`, as discussed in the last paragraph of https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#cant-find-standard-library-headers-map-stdioh-etc (MinGW is sort of like a "cross compiler" in this respect, in that it's a different target from clangd's point of view than the default MSVC).

So, you'd want to add `--query-driver=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe` to clangd's command line. This instructs clangd to query `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe` for its built-in include paths, which will include the standard library include paths.

Note that `--query-driver` needs to be specified as an argument to clangd itself, not in `compile_commands.json`. Clangd arguments are usually specified in an editor-specific place; I'm not sure offhand where that is for neovim.

---

One more thing to note: clangd will not find the `compile_commands.json` in `main_build` automatically. You need to copy it to `main` or an ancestor directory (like `c--_sampler`).

Alternatively, you can add `--compile-commands-dir=C:\Users\User\repos\c--_sampler\main_build` to clangd's arguments (same place as `--query-driver`), and then clangd will look for the `compile_commands.json` in that directory.

---

If you've tried the above and it's still not working, please feel free to post [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs) and we can take a look to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I found your answer, in combo with your answer I found to this related question [here](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/537), very helpful. also [this](https://github.com/williamboman/mason.nvim/discussions/57) with regards to `Mason`, `mason-lspconfig`, and `lspconfig`, along with the `:help` for all those

Answer (score 0):

As @HighCommander4 said, adding `--query-driver` as an argument to clangd solved the issue. (Copying `compile_commands.json` up a dir was also necessary)

I was able to do this by adding an `if else` statement that uses the `cmd` option to pass `--query-driver` inside `mason_lspconfig.setup_handlers` in `init.lua`

```
mason_lspconfig.setup_handlers {
  function(server_name)
    -- clangd cmd arguments here resolved missing header files error
    if server_name == 'clangd' then
      require('lspconfig')[server_name].setup {
        cmd = {'clangd', '--query-driver=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe'},
        capabilities = capabilities,
        on_attach = on_attach,
        settings = servers[server_name],
        filetypes = (servers[server_name] or {}).filetypes,
      }
    else
      require('lspconfig')[server_name].setup {
        capabilities = capabilities,
        on_attach = on_attach,
        settings = servers[server_name],
        filetypes = (servers[server_name] or {}).filetypes,
    }
    end
  end,
  -- adding my clangd cmd args here also solved missing header files, not sure which is more appropriate
  --[[["clangd"] = function()
    require('lspconfig')['clangd'].setup {
      cmd = {'clangd', '--query-driver=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe'}
      }
  end]]
}
```

There's probably a cleaner way to do this, but it's worked well to solve my problem