# CMakeFile results in linking error due to generated LLVM IR bitcode instead of ELF code

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to compile a c++-based project. Compilation/linking is controlled by the following CMakeLists.txt-file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(PROJECT_NAME "physics_variables")

project(${PROJECT_NAME} VERSION 1.10.0 DESCRIPTION "Physics variables and functions" LANGUAGES CXX)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

#C-Compilers have to be hardcoded, due to updates in CMake
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.10.0/bin/mpiicc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.10.0/bin/mpiicpc)

if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")
    set(CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -march=native -fopenmp-simd")
elseif("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Intel")
    set(CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -xHost")
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

cmake_policy (SET CMP0074 NEW)

set(C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${CXX_FLAGS} -mavx2 -fPIC -flto -fopenmp -O2 -funroll-loops -fstrict-aliasing")
set(CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CXX_FLAGS} -mavx2 -fPIC -flto -fopenmp -O2 -funroll-loops -fstrict-aliasing")

string(REPLACE " " ";" REPLACED_CXX_FLAGS ${CXX_FLAGS})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "")
find_package(Boost QUIET REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem mpi program_options serialization)

file(GLOB_RECURSE TARGET_SRC  "source/*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE TARGET_INC  "include/*.h" )
set(TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRS "./include" ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${TARGET_SRC})

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    SOVERSION 1
    UNITY_BUILD ON
    PUBLIC_HEADER ./include/physics_variables.h)

configure_file(physics_variables.pc.in physics_variables.pc @ONLY)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${REPLACED_CXX_FLAGS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    Boost::system
    Boost::filesystem
    Boost::program_options
    Boost::serialization)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}-targets
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
install(EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}-targets"
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME})
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
configure_package_config_file(
        "physics_variables.cmake.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
        INSTALL_DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}"
)
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}")
```

For compilation I use the IntelMPI-compilers (`mpiicpc`) with the Intel OneAPI-compiler (`-cxx=icpx`), which is set by exporting `I_MPI_CXX=icpx` before calling `cmake`. This results in the following compile line:

```
/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.10.0/bin/mpiicpc -DBOOST_ATOMIC_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_ATOMIC_NO_LIB -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_LIB -DBOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_NO_LIB -DBOOST_SERIALIZATION_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_SERIALIZATION_NO_LIB -DBOOST_SYSTEM_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_LIB -Dphysics_variables_EXPORTS -I/home/user/Documents/C++-Projects/physics_variables/./include -isystem /media/storage/local_opt/boost/include -fPIC -mavx2 -fPIC -flto -fopenmp -O2 -funroll-loops -fstrict-aliasing -std=gnu++17 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/physics_variables.dir/Unity/unity_1_cxx.cxx.o -MF CMakeFiles/physics_variables.dir/Unity/unity_1_cxx.cxx.o.d -o CMakeFiles/physics_variables.dir/Unity/unity_1_cxx.cxx.o -c /home/user/Documents/C++-Projects/physics_variables/CMakeFiles/physics_variables.dir/Unity/unity_1_cxx.cxx
```

After compiling the system tries to link the generated `cxx.o`-files using the following line:

```
"/usr/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -shared -o libphysics_variables.so.1.10.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtbeginS.o -L/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.10.0/lib/release -L/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.10.0/lib -L/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.2.1/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin -L/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.2.1/linux/bin-llvm/../lib -L/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.2.1/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../.. -L/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.2.1/linux/bin-llvm/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib -L/opt/intel/oneapi/tbb/2021.10.0/env/../lib/intel64/gcc4.8 -L/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.10.0//libfabric/lib -L/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.10.0//lib/release -L/opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.10.0//lib -L/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/2023.2.0/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/oneapi/ipp/2021.9.0/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/oneapi/ippcp/2021.8.0/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/oneapi/ipp/2021.9.0/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/oneapi/dnnl/2023.2.0/cpu_dpcpp_gpu_dpcpp/lib -L/opt/intel/oneapi/dal/2023.2.0/lib/intel64 -L/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.2.1/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin -L/opt/intel/oneapi/compiler/2023.2.1/linux/lib -L/opt/intel/oneapi/ccl/2021.10.0/lib/cpu_gpu_dpcpp -soname libphysics_variables.so.1 CMakeFiles/physics_variables.dir/Unity/unity_1_cxx.cxx.o CMakeFiles/physics_variables.dir/Unity/unity_0_cxx.cxx.o -rpath /media/storage/local_opt/boost/lib: /media/storage/local_opt/boost/lib/libboost_system.so.1.83.0 /media/storage/local_opt/boost/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.83.0 /media/storage/local_opt/boost/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.83.0 /media/storage/local_opt/boost/lib/libboost_serialization.so.1.83.0 /media/storage/local_opt/boost/lib/libboost_atomic.so.1.83.0 --enable-new-dtags -rpath /opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.10.0/lib/release -rpath /opt/intel/oneapi/mpi/2021.10.0/lib -lmpicxx -lmpifort -lmpi -ldl -lrt -lpthread -lsvml -lirng -lstdc++ -limf -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lintlc -ldl -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc -lirc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtendS.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

but fails with the following error:

```
CMakeFiles/physics_variables.dir/Unity/unity_1_cxx.cxx.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
icpx: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The error does not go away by rebuilding, as the `cxx.o`-files are `LLVM IR Bitcode`, and not the expected `ELF`-file, which can be linked. Is my CMakeLists.txt-file broken, or is something else not working as it should?

Edit: The modified reduced CMakeLists.txt-file contains:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(PROJECT_NAME physics_variables)
set(PROJECT_VERSION 1.10.0)

project(${PROJECT_NAME} VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION} DESCRIPTION "Physics variables and functions" LANGUAGES CXX)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

cmake_policy (SET CMP0074 NEW)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")

find_package(Boost QUIET REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem mpi program_options serialization)

file(GLOB_RECURSE TARGET_SRC  "source/*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE TARGET_INC  "include/*.h" )
set(TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRS "./include" ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${TARGET_SRC})

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    SOVERSION 1
    UNITY_BUILD ON
    INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION True
    PUBLIC_HEADER ./include/physics_variables.h)

configure_file(physics_variables.pc.in physics_variables.pc @ONLY)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

#target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${REPLACED_CXX_FLAGS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    Boost::system
    Boost::filesystem
    Boost::program_options
    Boost::serialization)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}-targets
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
install(EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}-targets"
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME})
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
configure_package_config_file(
        "physics_variables.cmake.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
        INSTALL_DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}"
)
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}Config.cmake"
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}")
```

Comment: Setting variables like `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` **after** the `project()` call is generally wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944545/3440745

Comment: Sidenote: Setting variable `set(PROJECT_NAME "physics_variables")` is confusing. The `project()` call itself sets that variable: [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_NAME.html). Just call `project(physics_variables VERSION 1.10.0 ...)` and the variable will be set automatically.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I changed those lines in accordance to the linked answer, but compilation still fails. Moreover, during testing of the compiler (as CMake is doing) everything works fine, it is only the main code which can't be compiled...

Comment: I am not an expert in Intel compilers, but generally one should inform CMake about all flags, which change output format of the compiler, prior the `project()` call. What option causes Intel compiler to generate object files containing LLVM IR Bitcode? If it is one of the options you set after the `project()` call, then you do it wrong. BTW, as far as I understand, if `-flto` is passed to the compiler, it should be passed to the linker too. Otherwise the linker won't perform the optimizations of the source code.

Comment: "I changed those lines in accordance to the linked answer, but compilation still fails." - Please, update the code in your question post to reflect that change. I find a little interest in debugging weird errors, which are caused by changing the compiler after CMake has checked it in `project()` call.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't know yet what causes these flags, but updated the question with the revised CMakeLists.txt-file