# Compiling ffmpeg into wasm with emscripten

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, linker, emscripten

I'm trying to integrate ffmpeg directly into my WebAssembly-project.

A friend of mine provided me link to a project https://github.com/alfg/ffmpeg-webassembly-example/tree/master which does almost exactly what I'm trying to achieve. It compiles ffmpeg and creates wasm with the necessary bindings to make it usable from Javascript.

But instead of building Javascript bindings - like in that example, I would like to make a single stand-alone wasm file that contains ffmpeg.
I would like to use CMake for the building process and I've been trying to use that within docker similarly to how the example is built.
But I'm having difficulties linking the ffmpeg.
I get a couple duplicate symbol errors at the end of the build process:

```
wasm-ld: error: duplicate symbol: emscripten_compute_dom_pk_code
>>> defined in /emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/pic/libhtml5.a(dom_pk_codes.o)
>>> defined in /emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/pic/libhtml5.a(dom_pk_codes.o)

wasm-ld: error: duplicate symbol: emscripten_dom_pk_code_to_string
>>> defined in /emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/pic/libhtml5.a(dom_pk_codes.o)
>>> defined in /emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/pic/libhtml5.a(dom_pk_codes.o)

wasm-ld: error: duplicate symbol: emscripten_dom_vk_to_string
>>> defined in /emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/pic/libhtml5.a(key_codes.o)
>>> defined in /emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/pic/libhtml5.a(key_codes.o)
```

So it seems like libhtml5 library is linked multiple times during the build process.
Is there some way to disable linking the dependencies to that - if that is the issue. Or is there some way to just ignore the duplicate symbol error and force the software to use the first implementation or something?

My project can be found at git https://github.com/ppxxy/VideoService/tree/master and the Readme contains steps to build the project using docker.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
The CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(DCMAKE_SH="CMAKE_SH-NOTFOUND")

set(PROJECT_NAME VideoPlayer)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

message("Build system is " ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME})

include(FetchContent)

file(GLOB_RECURSE PROJECT_SOURCE_FILES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS src/*.cpp src/*.html)

file(GLOB_RECURSE UTILS CONFIGURE_DEPENDS src/utils/*.cpp)

file(GLOB_RECURSE MESH CONFIGURE_DEPENDS src/mesh/*.cpp)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "emcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "em++")

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /emsdk/upstream/emscripten/system/include)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_FILES})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache/ports/freetype/FreeType-version_1/include 
/usr/local/include
/opt/ffmepg/include
)

set(EMCC_CFLAGS "-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1")
#-sASYNCIFY or -fwasm-exceptions, can't mix those 2.
set(USE_FLAGS "-s USE_SDL=2 -s FETCH=1 -sASYNCIFY -sNO_DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING -gsource-map --source-map-base ./")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${USE_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${USE_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${USE_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX ".html")

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

# The path name to a skeleton HTML file used when generating HTML output.
# The shell file used needs to have this token inside it: {{{ SCRIPT }}}.
target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC --shell-file ./src/index.html -gsource-map -v -sMAIN_MODULE=1 -sUSE_WEBGPU=1 -sNO_FILESYSTEM=1 -sASSERTIONS=1 -sMALLOC=emmalloc -sALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -pthread --closure=1 -static-libstdc++ -std=c++17 -lhtml5 -fsanitize=undefined)

include_directories(src/)

add_library(libavformat STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libavformat PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavformat.a)
set_target_properties(libavformat PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES /opt/ffmpeg/include)

add_library(libavfilter STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libavfilter PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavfilter.a)
set_target_properties(libavfilter PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES /opt/ffmpeg/include)

add_library(libavdevice STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libavdevice PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavdevice.a)
set_target_properties(libavdevice PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES /opt/ffmpeg/include)

add_library(libswresample STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libswresample PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /opt/ffmpeg/lib/libswresample.a)
set_target_properties(libswresample PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES /opt/ffmpeg/include)

add_library(libpostproc STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libpostproc PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /opt/ffmpeg/lib/libpostproc.a)
set_target_properties(libpostproc PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES /opt/ffmpeg/include)

add_library(libswscale STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libswscale PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /opt/ffmpeg/lib/libswscale.a)
set_target_properties(libswscale PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES /opt/ffmpeg/include)

add_library(libavutil STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libavutil PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /opt/ffmpeg/lib/libavutil.a)
set_target_properties(libavutil PROPERTIES INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES /opt/ffmpeg/include)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
libavformat libavfilter libavdevice libswresample libpostproc libswscale libavutil
-lm
)
```

and Dockerfile pretty much identical to that of the reference project's:

```
FROM emscripten/emsdk:3.1.40 as build

ARG FFMPEG_VERSION=4.3.2
ARG X264_VERSION=20170226-2245-stable

ARG PREFIX=/opt/ffmpeg
ARG MAKEFLAGS="-j4"

# Build dependencies.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y autoconf libtool build-essential

# Download and build x264.
RUN cd /tmp && \
  wget https://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/x264/snapshots/x264-snapshot-${X264_VERSION}.tar.bz2 && \
  tar xvfj x264-snapshot-${X264_VERSION}.tar.bz2

RUN cd /tmp/x264-snapshot-${X264_VERSION} && \
  emconfigure ./configure \
  --prefix=${PREFIX} \
  --host=i686-gnu \
  --enable-static \
  --disable-cli \
  --disable-asm \
  --extra-cflags="-s USE_PTHREADS=1 -sSIDE_MODULE=1"

RUN cd /tmp/x264-snapshot-${X264_VERSION} && \
  emmake make && emmake make install 

# Download ffmpeg release source.
RUN cd /tmp/ && \
  wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
  tar zxf ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz && rm ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz

ARG CFLAGS="-s USE_PTHREADS=1 -O3 -I${PREFIX}/include -sSIDE_MODULE=1"
ARG LDFLAGS="$CFLAGS -L${PREFIX}/lib -s INITIAL_MEMORY=33554432"

# Configure and build FFmpeg with emscripten.
# Disable all programs and only enable features we will use.
# https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/configure
RUN cd /tmp/ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION} && \
  emconfigure ./configure \
  --prefix=${PREFIX} \
  --target-os=none \
  --arch=x86_32 \
  --enable-cross-compile \
  --disable-debug \
  --disable-x86asm \
  --disable-inline-asm \
  --disable-stripping \
  --disable-programs \
  --disable-doc \
  --disable-all \
  --enable-avcodec \
  --enable-avformat \
  --enable-avfilter \
  --enable-avdevice \
  --enable-avutil \
  --enable-swresample \
  --enable-postproc \
  --enable-swscale \
  --enable-filters \
  --enable-protocol=file \
  --enable-decoder=h264,aac,pcm_s16le \
  --enable-demuxer=mov,matroska \
  --enable-muxer=mp4 \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --extra-cflags="$CFLAGS" \
  --extra-cxxflags="$CFLAGS" \
  --extra-ldflags="$LDFLAGS" \
  --nm="llvm-nm -g" \
  --ar=emar \
  --as=llvm-as \
  --ranlib=llvm-ranlib \
  --cc=emcc \
  --cxx=em++ \
  --objcc=emcc \
  --dep-cc=emcc

RUN cd /tmp/ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION} && \
  emmake make -j4 && \
  emmake make install

WORKDIR /build
```

Comment: Please, add relevant **code** to the **question post** itself. This is a requirement of Stack Overflow, and links to the code doesn't fulfil that requirement. See e.g. [ask] or [mcve].

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm not sure if CMakeLists.txt can be considered code? It's more of a set of build instructions rather than code.

Comment: `CMakeLists.txt` is a **code**. With that code you specify compiler and linker options. Well, you may provide instead the complete command line used for linker. But if you want to fix not the command line but `CMakeLists.txt`, you need to show the latter. BTW, it still could be useful to examine the linker's command line and check the actual parameters passed to the linker.

Comment: Concerning your `CMakeLists.txt`, it is incorrect to set variables `CMAKE_C_COMPILER`/`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` after the project call: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944545/3440745. The **libraries** for link with should specified with `target_link_libraries` command; specifying libraries in the `target_link_options` (like you do with `-lhtml5`) places that parameter for the linker in the wrong place. Also, `-std=c++17` is a **compiler** option, so its specification with `target_link_options` is wrong too.