# How can I use cmake with Tasking compiler?

Tags: cmake

I try to create a cmake project to build a static library with the TASKING compiler.
I set the compiler path but when I run the cmake generator, I have the following error:

```
Compiling the C

compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: C:/Tools/TASKING/TriCore v6.3r1/ctc/bin/cc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 
  
The output was:
no such file or directory
```

I think, cmake tries to compile the C file with options from gcc Compiler.
Any idea?
I also have seen, that there is a variable `CMAKE_TASKING_TOOLSET`, but the documentation is not so good, I tried the following:

```
set(CMAKE_TASKING_TOOLSET true)
```

but nothing changed.

From cmake.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

# Set the C compiler and archiver
set(ENV{PATH} "C:/TASKING/TriCore v6.3r1/ctc/bin/")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ctc.exe) 
set(CMAKE_AR artc.exe)
project(Aurix LANGUAGES C)
set(CMAKE_TASKING_TOOLSET true)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic-ELF)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR tricore)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-tC")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT " ")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

set(CMAKE_C_RESPONSE_FILE_LINK_FLAG "-f")
```

Comment: Variables like `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` should be set in the **toolchain file**. Setting them in the  `CMakeLists.txt` after the `project()` call is wrong: exactly `project()` call causes CMake to check compilers. See [that my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944545/3440745).

Comment: Also, setting `PATH` environment variable in the `CMakeLists.txt` is quite misleading: while that variable could help CMake to find the compiler when configure the project, the variable won't be set when your project will actually be built. Instead, specify absolute paths in `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_AR` variables.

Comment: `set(CMAKE_TASKING_TOOLSET true)` true is not a valid value. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TASKING_TOOLSET.html

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried also the other options but still error messages

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried all your suggestions but still I have error messages

Comment: "I have the following error" - What you show is NOT the error you got. You show the content of `CMakeErrorLog.txt` file. That content could be useful sometimes. But the main error message is printed by CMake in the **output** (**terminal**). Please, copy paste to the question post that message and all previous lines from output **exactly**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I found a solution of an other project with Tasking in internet, I will post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found in internet a project with Tasking and cmake so now it looks good, I dont have any problems with the compiler and the code looks like the following.
Maybe there is a better solution but this one it works.

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID_RUN TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID_RUN TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")

#TASKING_PATH
SET(CCPATH "C:/TASKING/TriCore_v6.3r1/")

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${CCPATH}/ctc/bin/cctc.exe")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${CCPATH}/ctc/bin/cctc.exe")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_VERSION "6.3r1")

SET(CC "${CCPATH}/ctc/bin/cctc.exe")
SET(CXX "${CCPATH}/ctc/bin/cctc.exe")
SET(CMAKE_LINKER "${CCPATH}/ctc/bin/ltc.exe")
SET(CMAKE_AR "${CCPATH}/ctc/bin/artc.exe" CACHE FILEPATH "Archiver")


SET(CMAKE_C_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_LIBRARIES 1)
SET(CMAKE_C_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_INCLUDES 1)
SET(CMAKE_C_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_OBJECTS 1)

# Without "-f" the responsible file flag will be "@" which is not handled by 
tasking compiler
# So we need to set them as below
SET(CMAKE_C_RESPONSE_FILE_LINK_FLAG "-f ")
SET(CMAKE_C_RESPONSE_FILE_FLAG "-f ")
SET(CMAKE_C_OUTPUT_EXTENSION ".o")
SET(CMAKE_START_TEMP_FILE "-f ")

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_C_COMPILER> <FLAGS> <DEFINES> <INCLUDES> -o <OBJECT> <SOURCE>")
SET(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE "${CMAKE_LINKER} <OBJECTS> <LINK_LIBRARIES> <CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> --output=<TARGET>.elf:ELF --output=<TARGET>.hex:IHEX --output=<TARGET>.sre:SREC")
# Don't know how to set this on project level (not in toolchain file)
SET(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_CREATE "<CMAKE_AR> -r -c -v <LINK_FLAGS> <TARGET> <OBJECTS>")
SET(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_APPEND "<CMAKE_AR> --replace <LINK_FLAGS> <TARGET> <OBJECTS>")
SET(CMAKE_C_ARCHIVE_FINISH "")

project(Aurix LANGUAGES C)
```