"relative path" error message in cmake configure
I try to build a "towers of hanoi" tutorial C program using ncurses in my windows/msys2 based environment with VS code as IDE. Gcc, make, cmake and all the rest is installed correctly and works fine on command line basis. As I understand, saving changes to CMakeLists.txt in VSC will run a cmake configure. But in my case this results in the error message
[cmake] CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
[cmake]   Found relative path while evaluating include directories of "hanoi.exe":
[cmake] 
[cmake]     "C:/Projekte/Programming/hanoi/C:/msys64/usr/include"

to me this looks like by some magic the project path is prepended to the include path but I can't see why or where this has to be changed. If I delete the build and c[] direktories in the project folder before saving CMakeLists.txt the same happens but for a CMake include:
[cmake] CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI.cmake:85 (file):
[cmake]   file STRINGS file
[cmake]   "C:/Projekte/Programming/hanoi/c:/Projekte/Programming/hanoi/build/CMakeFiles/3.26.4/CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin"
[cmake]   cannot be read.

As a result the build command, started from VSC fails (because it trys to start previously unsuccessful configure?). So does the intellisense function in VSC editor, that tells me that the ncurses include could not be found. (But when I open the include by F12 in VSC it is immediately found and opened) I already tried target_include_directories instead of include_directories but that does not change anything.
My C source can be found on https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/intro.html#WHATIS The first lines are:
#include <curses.h>

#define POSX 10
#define POSY 5
#define DISC_CHAR '*'
#define PEG_CHAR '#'
#define TIME_OUT 300
  ...

The ncurses include is in C:\msys64\ucrt64\include\ncurses,
my project path is C:/Projekte/Programming/hanoi/ while the msys2 installation is in C:/msys64/ my CMakeLists.txt is
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
project(hanoi.exe VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C)

Set(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM  "C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\make.exe")
Set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER    "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\gcc.exe")

include_directories("C:\\msys64\\usr\\include" "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\include") 

set(SOURCE_FILES hanoi.c) 

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ncurses)

my c_cpp_properties.json is
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\include\\**",
                "C:\\msys64\\usr\\include\\**",
                "${workspaceFolder}\\**" 
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

Any hints where to fix this or which tutorial on cmake or vsc I should consult?

I have tried the recommendations from HolyBlackCat and reinstalled
mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc and mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-cmake. I then reduced my CMakeLists.txt to
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
project(hanoi VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C)
set(SOURCE_FILES hanoi.c)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ncurses)

running cmake in MSYS terminal does not work due to missing paths in unix style.
$ cmake -S . build
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

In windows PS or VSC terminal this seems to work.
cmake -S . build
-- Building for: Ninja
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.1.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/cc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Configuring done (0.5s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Projekte/Programming/hanoi/build

building the target by cmake fails because curses.h cannot be found.
cmake --build build
[1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/hanoi.dir/hanoi.c.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/hanoi.dir/hanoi.c.obj 
C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\cc.exe    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/hanoi.dir/hanoi.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\hanoi.dir\hanoi.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/hanoi.dir/hanoi.c.obj -c C:/Projekte/Programming/hanoi/hanoi.c
C:/Projekte/Programming/hanoi/hanoi.c:1:10: fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <curses.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed

That was the point when I initially but fruitlessly tried to add the path with include_directories or target_include_directories which -according to HolyBlackCat (and my understanding) - is not necessary. But how else can I give the hint to the directory?

What's up with all the hardcoded paths in CMakeLists.txt? You need none of that. Remove both Sets and include_directories (also drop .exe from the project name). Make sure you have installed pacman -S mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-cmake as opposed to just gcc and cmake. And you definitely don't want anything in C:\msys64\usr to participate in the build, that's for a different environment. If this doesn't work, please show the new CMake logs.

Before building in VSC, make sure you can successfully build in the terminal (use MSYS2 UCRT64 terminal to get the correct PATH and other environment variables).

Setting variable CMAKE_C_COMPILER after the project call is wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63944545/3440745. Similar for CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM variable. Normally, those settings should NOT be performed at all in the project. If you got some errors without that settings, then you are better to concentrate on that errors instead.

Please, do not post (multiline) code in the comments. Instead, [edit] the question post itself. On Stack Overflow a question post is expected to contain all information about the problem, which is sufficient to answer. Comments are for clarification requests.

Using commands include_directories or target_include_directories is a correct way for add include directories. Some include directories are added automatically by the compiler. E.g. I would expect a MSYS compiler adding path C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\include automatically. But I don't think that a compiler adds automatically a directory ended with ncurses.

Note, that because your configure the project for MSYS environment, the absolute paths should be written in form /C/other/path/components. See e.g. that question.

with the help of @HolyBlackCat and @Tsyvarev I finally found a working CMakeLists.txt. The ncurses specific directories have been added as well as the STATIC directive to enable linking in the windows environment.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
project(hanoi VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C)
set(SOURCE_FILES hanoi.c)
include_directories("C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\include\\ncurses")
link_directories("C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\lib")
add_compile_options(-DNCURSES_STATIC)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ncurses)


I'm glad it worked, but again, hardcoding paths in a CMakeLists.txt is a very bad sign. You want it to be cross-platform and not locked to a specific installation directory. You should try to automate finding the paths using (I think?) find_package.
