# What is the difference between DEFS and CPPFLAGS in autoconf and automake

Tags: autoconf, automake

I already read about the difference between [CFLAGS and CPPFLAGS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754966/cflags-vs-cppflags). But my Makefile.am currently uses both DEFS and CPPFLAGS and I am not sure about the difference.

```
DEFS += -DLOCALEDIR=\"$(localedir)\" -DDATADIR=\"$(datadir)\" -DPKGDATADIR=\"$(pkgdatadir)\"
```

and:

```
src_foo_CPPFLAGS = \
    $(AM_CPPFLAGS) \
    -I$(top_builddir)/src \
    -DDATADIR='"$(datadir)"' \
    -DMODULEDIR='"$(moduledir)"' \
    -DLIBEXECDIR='"$(libexecdir)"'
```

Both the CPPFLAGS and the DEFS seems to create *defines* with the `-D` option. So whats the difference. Can I remove `DEFS` and just add the missing defines (`PKGDATADIR` and `LOCALEDIR`) to `CPPFLAGS`?

Comment: The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Installation-Directory-Variables.html) suggests the way to do this is through `CPPFLAGS`/`AM_CPPFLAGS`: "you should add -DDATADIR='$(datadir)' to your makefile's definition of CPPFLAGS".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DEFS` is defined in autoconf as follows:

> -D options to pass to the C compiler. If AC_CONFIG_HEADERS is called, configure replaces ‘@DEFS@’ with -DHAVE_CONFIG_H instead (see
>   Configuration Headers). This variable is not defined while configure
>   is performing its tests, only when creating the output files. See
>   Setting Output Variables, for how to check the results of previous
>   tests.

When make is executed with the `-p` flag (e.g. `make -p > rules`). We can examine the resulting `rules` file to find out what make make will actually do.

Assuming the `AC_CONFIG_HEADERS` macro is called then `DEFS` is initially defined as follows:

```
DEFS = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
```

Assuming we define `DEFS` as follows:

```
DEFS += \
    -DLOCALEDIR=\"$(localedir)\" \
    -DDATADIR=\"$(datadir)\" \
    -DPKGDATADIR=\"$(pkgdatadir)\"
```

then `DEFS` is going to look like this:

```
DEFS = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DLOCALEDIR=\"$(localedir)\" -DDATADIR=\"$(datadir)\"  \
       -DPKGDATADIR=\"$(pkgdatadir)\"
```

Next lets look at the way `DEFS` is used in the Makefiles that are generated by automake, the compile rule in the Makefile will look like this:

```
COMPILE = $(CC) $(DEFS) $(DEFAULT_INCLUDES) $(INCLUDES) $(AM_CPPFLAGS) \
          $(CPPFLAGS) $(AM_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
```

As we can see, `DEFS` appears first, followed by some other variables and the `AM_CPPFLAGS`
Every further occurrence of `DEFS` is always followed by another occurrence of `AM_CPPFLAGS` and its variants such as `foo_CPPFLAGS`.

So to conclude this question, I think its clear that `DEFS` can be removed and instead its content can be put into `CPPFLAGS`. I also asked this question on IRC in the autotools channel. It was suggested to me, not to use `DEFS` and only use `CPPFLAGS`.