# -Wall flag not working from Makefile

Tags: compiler-construction, makefile

When I run "g++ -Wall programName.cpp" the compiler outputs warnings about unused variables, but when I use the Makefile to compile, these warnings do not appear. I have the

```
OBJS = test.o

# Name of executable
NAME = ../test

# Flags to pass to the compiler. 
CFLAGS = -Wall

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
   g++ $(CFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS)
```

in my Makefile, but doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know what could be causing this???

When I run the make I get the output:

```
 g++    -c -o test.o test.cpp
 g++ -Wall -o test test.o
```

It seems like the -Wall is only being applied to the process of turning the .o file into an executable, not the part of .cpp -> .o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the built-in rule for going from `OBJS` to `NAME`, but not the rule for compling `.cpp` to`.o`.

The proper fix would appear to be to not override any built-in rules, and instead adding `-Wall` to the correct flags variable for the built-in rules (I guess in this case `CXXFLAGS`). See also [Difference between CPPFLAGS and CXXFLAGS in GNU Make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495598/difference-between-cppflags-and-cxxflags-in-gnu-make)

Comment: Yep, this was the problem. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The variable is named `CFLAGS`, not `CLAGS`.

Comment: Was a typo when entering the question...sorry. I had CFLAGS

Comment: Then, there's absolutely nothing we can do to help you with the information you've provided.  That statement will set CFLAGS to that value.  Great.  So obviously if you're not seeing that flag on your compile line, then the problem is somewhere else in your makefile.