# GCC - define my own command line option that adds a list of options

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings

Using GCC to compile C++ code: there's a big list of options (warnings, optimisations etc) I want to always compile with. It's tiresome to keep pasting them into the command line. Can I do something like

```
g++ test.cpp -o test.o -myoptions
```

where "-myoptions" would enable a list of options like

```
-pedantic
-Wall
-O2
-Wshadow
-...
```

that I've defined somewhere?

I've tried searching but couldn't find a guide for this. Is it possible or do I have to use make files? System is windows 7 if that's relevant. Thanks

---

edit: in case someone searches for this in the future, windows specific answer: go to control panel -> system -> advanced system settings -> environment variables, create new system variable named "myoptions" and value "-option1 -option2 -option3 ...". Then compile with "g++ test.cpp -o test.o %myoptions%"

Comment: Just use some of the many existing build systems, or even write your own makefiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an environment variable:

```
export CXXFLAGS="-Wall -O3 -std=c++11"
```

and use

```
g++ $CXXFLAGS test.cc -o test
```

Note that some variables are more-or-less standardized and when you set them, several build system will automatically use them. Among others, google for `CFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`, ...

Here's also a [starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495598) on SO.

Comment: Assuming a Unix-y OS, or Cygwin on the Windows OP is using of course.

Comment: Thanks, environment variable route works great! 

Though, windows doesn't find CXXFLAGS, so edited in a windows specific answer

Comment: @fvu The usual Windows shells also support environment variables, albeit with a different syntax (`SET CXXFLAGS=...` to set, `g++ %CXXFLAGS% ...` to use).