# adding c++11 in makefile to remove the error to_string is not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I suppose this question is asked in some other threads, I was getting the error while calling make: to_string is not declared in this scope. I found out I have to add c++11 in makefile. But I tried some options mentioned in several threads. Could you provide some solution here? Thanks

Comment: can you post a minimal complete example please so that we can start to think about what might be wrong?

Comment: This is my makefile http://1drv.ms/1JTD6T6, I could not add all the contents due to space limit

Comment: I presume you're using g++. This compiler is strong on standard-conformance for the core language, but weak on the standard library (takes long to catch up). Thus there is a distinct possibility that `to_string` is actually missing, depending on the version. Complementing this, Microsoft's compiler is weak on standard-conformance for the core language, but strong on the standard library. Perhaps due to efforts of STL. (That's a person, not the Standard Template Library: at Microsoft, STL maintains the STL).

Comment: @namanarora: please do narrow your code down to a **minimal but complete example**. thank you.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf Is this ok? I am not sure about minimal but complete example, these are the contents of the make file, other things are normal, probably here is some thing missing: CC=g++
LD=g++
CFLAGS=-c -g -O3 -finline-functions -fstack-protector

Comment: And I also ran on Mac, it was working there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `-std=c++11` to `CFLAGS` will cause `g++` to compile with the C++11 standard. Like this

```
CFLAGS=-std=c++11 -c -g -O3 -finline-functions -fstack-protector
```

---

However, as highlighted in comments the appropriate syntax for compiling C++ programs with a `makefile` is to use a rule like this

```
$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c
```

where your C++ files use the suffix `.cc` [[1](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules)]. Then you would add `-std=c++11` to `CXXFLAGS`. The difference between `CPPFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` is [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495598/difference-between-cppflags-and-cxxflags-in-gnu-make)]

> CPPFLAGS is supposed to be for flags for the **C** **P**re**P**rocessor; CXXFLAGS
>   is for flags for the C++ compiler.

This would require some rewrites within your `makefile`, namely

```
CXX=g++
LD=g++
CXXFLAGS=-c -g -O3 -fstack-protector -I./Eigen
```

and rules from

```
$(CC) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) -c
```

to

```
$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c
```

as above.

The `$(INCLUDE)` can also be removed from your linking command (`$(LD)`) as it is only needed during compile time. Your linking command can also be simplified to

```
ParEGOIteration13: ParEGOIteration13.o Utilities.o WeightVector.o SearchSpace.o DACE.o GeneticAlgorithm.o Matrix.o
    $(CXX) $? -o $@
```

by using the automatic variables [[3](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)]

- `$?` expands to all of the prerequisites
- `$@` expands to the name of the target

I'll let you work out how to use the automatic variables in your compilation rules.

**Note:** I've removed `-finline-functions` as `-O3` (and `-O2`) turn it on by default with [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options).

Comment: Actually that should be `CXXFLAGS` not `CFLAGS` ;)

Comment: In the `makefile` posted in the comments that would require much more significant changes.

Comment: "much more significant change", you mean also changing `CC` to `CXX` ? The guy is learning things, doesn't hurt to give him full infos/advice while you're at it :)

Comment: @Drax I've updated the answer based on your comments. I think I've covered most of the basics to help the guy out now.

Comment: Holy cow, didn't expect that much, nice answer :)