# cgo doesn't include CXXFLAGS

Tags: c++11, go, cgo

I want to call C code in Golang:

```
// #cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/include/c++/8.1.1/bits
// #cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=gnu++11
// #include "c++0x_warning.h"
import "C"
```

but get error:

```
In file included from ./main.go:5:
/usr/include/c++/8.1.1/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

So cgo doesn't use CXXFLAGS. I tried `-std=c++11` and it doesn't work too. What I do wrong?

```
$ go version
go version go1.10.3 linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following SO question: [Difference between CPPFLAGS and CXXFLAGS in GNU Make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495598/difference-between-cppflags-and-cxxflags-in-gnu-make#495646) to figure out which flags you really need in the context of your program.

If you are calling pure C code (and not C++ code), I don't think you will need `CXX_FLAGS`:

> `CPPFLAGS` are supposed to be flags for the C PreProcessor; `CXXFLAGS` are flags for the C++ compiler.

You might also want to check your `go env`. If you really need this flag, you can try to compile your program using `env CGO_CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11" go build <YOUR_CODE>`.